# VS2010/Framework 4.0 - Getting the max value of an enum

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, enums

I'm looking to get the min and max value of an enum not the max amount of enumerators.  I've seen [Getting the max value of an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203377/getting-the-max-value-of-an-enum)

However, in Framework 4, cast() doesn't exist for GetValues().

Example:

```
public enum Foo
{
     Bird = 1,
     Cat = 2,
     Dog = 4,
     Hampster = 8
}

var last = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo)).Cast<int>().Max();

Result should be: 8
```

Anyone know how this is done in framework 4 without having to enumerate through it all myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerable.Cast<T>()` is an extension method and was introduced in .NET 3.5

Are you missing a `using System.Linq;` statement?

You need that namespace to find the extension method.

Comment: Guess I was, thanks. It will not let me accept for the next 9 minutes.