# Getting the max value of enum via LINQ and only given the enum type

Tags: c#, linq, enums, runtime

I know the how to get the max value of a enum has an answer here: [Getting the max value of an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203377/getting-the-max-value-of-an-enum).

My question is different: I need to write a function `GetMax` which only takes the `Type` of the enum as parameter, and I need to get the max value of the enum. Meanwhile, my enum may derive from `long` or `int`. To avoid overflow, the max value returned should be numerical `long`. 
Here is the function declaration:

```
long GetMax(Type type);
```

I have implemented the function like below:

```
static private long GetMax(Type type)
{
    long maxValue = 0;
    if (Enum.GetValues(type).Length != 0)
    {
        maxValue = Int64.MinValue;
        foreach (var x in Enum.GetValues(type))
        {
            maxValue = Math.Max(maxValue, Convert.ToInt64(x));
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

I think the function can be implemented via LINQ to simplified the code, but I don't know how to do that. I tried like:

```
long maxValue = Convert.ToInt64(Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<???>().ToList().Max());
```

But I don't know what to fill in the **Cast<>**, because I only know the type of the enum.

Is there any solution to simplify the code via LINQ? Thx!

Comment: maybe use of `.Select(x => Convert.ToInt64(x))` instead of `.Cast<T>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realise, that `GetValues` return an `Array`, so `.Select()` is not available, so you need to `.Cast<Enum>()` before:

```
long maxValue = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Select(x => Convert.ToInt64(x)).Max();
```

Also, if you need a an actual enum value, you may use:

```
var maxValue = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().Max();
```

Comment: Yes, we must use `.Cast<T>()` to convert `Array` to `IEnumerable<T>` so that `.Select` can work. So the main point of this question is if we don't know `YOUR ENUM`, how can we cast it? So far we know that we can cast it into `Enum` and `object`.

Comment: @Caesium actualy, instead of `.Cast<T>()` you may use `.OfType<T>()`. Difference here, in case of `.OfType<T>()`, is that if one element of `Array` will be not  of type `T` it will be skipped. `.Cast<T>()` in such situation will throw `CastException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a generic method.

```
static private T GetMax<T>(Type type)
{
    T maxValue = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<T>().Max();
    return maxValue;
}
```

Then you just need to pass your expect data type.

```
GetMax<long>(typeof(Color))
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BN3gCQ)

Comment: No, it won't work, I already tried before. CastException will be thrown. System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApp7.Color' to type 'System.Int64'.'

Comment: You can try to see my c# online

Comment: The exception will be thrown via run and compile the program via Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Did your enum do `enum Color : long` for long?

Comment: no, because my enum may also derived from `int`, if it derive from `int`, exception will be thrown.

Comment: You gived me the inspiration! We can cast it into `object`: `return Convert.ToInt64(Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>().Max());`

Answer (score 1):

I found out a method, we can cast the enum into `object`:

```
return Convert.ToInt64(Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<object>().Max());
```