# Can i restrict this c# extension method definition with a WHERE keyword?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

i'm trying to do the following extension method -> converting an int to a enum, when you provide the enum :-

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this int value)
{
    return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
}
```

Now, i was hoping to make it so that you can only define the type T to be an enumeration. Is there any what i can restrict it?

eg.

```
int day = 3;
DaysOfWeek dow = day<DaysOfWeek>(); // No compiler error.
DaysOfWeek dow2 = day<Foo>(); // Compiler error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Where T: struct

See this Question
[Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)