# Are there any built in helper methods to display enumerations in a dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have enumerations that I need to display in a dropdownlist, and have them pre-populated in my admin pages.

Are there any built in html helpers for this already?

(asp.net mvc)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc/694361#694361)

Given the enum

```
public enum Status
{ 
    Current = 1, 
    Pending = 2, 
    Cancelled = 3 
}
```

And the Extension Method

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
{
  var values = from TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
               select new { ID = e, Name = e.ToString() };

  return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
ViewData["taskStatus"] = task.Status.ToSelectList();
```

Comment: is there a way to put the ID value in the select options value attribute, instead of the text?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: `return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Id", enumObj);`

Comment: Tried that, it is still showing option value=current, I want value=1

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary to Robert Harvey's answer, using the DescriptionAttribute will allow you to handle enum values that have multiple words, e.g.:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  [Description("Not Applicable")]
  NotApplicable,
  Yes,
  No
}
```

You can grab the `DescriptionAttribute` value if it exists and then use `descriptionAttributeText ?? enumMemberName` as the display text for your drop-down.