# Can I pass an enum into a controller so the Model Binder binds it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, model-binding

if so, how should i pass the parameter? would a string matching the enum name be ok? This would be handy if I was passing a dropdown box that matched enumerated items.

It would be useful to use a solution presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc/694361#694361) if I could just as easily bind to the enum when I submit the data back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, when having a controller like:

```
enum MyAction { Lalala }

public ActionResult Index(MyAction action) { ... }
```

You can just do `Index/Lalala`, and everything works fine.

If you need more complex binding (like mapping a certain string value to a complex class), use something like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

It gets even better you can also pass `Enum` as get parameter

```
@Html.ActionLink("Email Quote", "UnitDetails", "Journey", new { product = product.ProductTitle, button = "email" }, new { @class = "btn btn--main btn--main-orange" })
```

that ends up following url: `http://localhost:50766/UnitDetails?product=Your%20quote&button=email`

Action method that accepts looks like this:

```
    [SessionTimeout]
    public ActionResult UnitDetails(QuoteViewModel viewModel)
```

QuoteViewModel and enum:

```
public class QuoteViewModel : IQuoteViewModel
{
    public QuoteViewModelProducts Products { get; set; }

    public bool HasDiscount { get; set; }

    public string Product { get; set; }

    public DetailButtonType Button { get; set; }
}

public enum DetailButtonType
{
    Buy,
    Callback,
    Email
}
```

What I love most is even if you pass enum parameter and value as lowercase it maps correctly to Uppercase property and Value, which makes my grin profusely.

[image]