# How to use a Html.DropDownList in a strongly-typed view for a model containing a nullable enum property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model class as follows:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female };
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select either Female or Male.")]
        public Sex? Sex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `Edit` action does :

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var Person = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Someone", Sex = Sex.Male };
            return View(Person);
        }
    }
}
```

## Question 1

How to mark up the `Edit` view such that there is a dropdown control containing 3 options: "--Select--", "Female", and "Male". For the `Person` passed to the view, "Male" must be selected.

## Question 2

How to make up the `Create` view and leave the dropdown control selecting  "--Select--" by default.

Here is the `Create` action:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
       var Person = new Person();
       return View(Person);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [good answer already on how to convert an Enum into a SelectList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc) but I'll reuse that code inline to simply the answer.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var Person = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Someone", Sex = Sex.Male };
    List<object> values = new List<object>();
    values.Add(new { ID = "choose", Name = "--Select--" });
    values.AddRange(from Sex sex in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Sex))
            select new { ID = sex, Name = sex.ToString() });            
    ViewData["sexes"] = new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Person.Sex);
    return View(Person);
}
```

Now the Edit.cshtml view:

```
@model Test.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sex)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">            
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sex, (SelectList)ViewData["sexes"])
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sex)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Now the control action to post the form to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
{
    var newName = person.Name;
    var newSex = person.Sex;

    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
}
```

Now run the project in debug mode with a break on the `return RedirectToAction("index", "home");` line in the post-to Edit action. See how you can change form values in the view and then do what you need to do in the posted-to action? There are other options than using ViewData to pass the list but they complicate the example and are plentiful.

The `Create` action would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    List<object> values = new List<object>();
    values.Add(new { ID = "choose", Name = "--Select--" });
    values.AddRange(from Sex sex in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Sex))
            select new { ID = sex, Name = sex.ToString() });
    ViewData["sexes"] = new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");
    return View(person);
}
```

The default select list item will be the first one so it would show "--Select--" as the default choice.

Comment: First of all, thank  you very much. Can I promote the `Edit.cshtml` to be `Person.cshtml`? When I use `Person.cshtml` for `Create` action, does the dropdown select "--Select--" by default?

Comment: I'll edit and add the --Select-- part right now. The Edit action will use by convention the Edit view. You can force it to use a different view like so: `return View("Person", Person)`. However, it makes more sense to to have a Edit and a Create view that share a common EditPerson partial for the form. That way you can still say "Edit" or "Create" on the page and have the details about edit or create but share the form work.

Comment: To share a common partial for the form, create a new partial view called `EditPerson` and then in the edit and create views where you want the form put `@Html.RenderPartial("EditPerson", Model)` which will pass the view model down to the partial. The contents of the `EditPerson` partial could be everything below `<h2>Edit</h2>`.

Comment: "--Select--" can be passed to the third arg of `Html.DropDownListFor`. But I don't know which one is the better way, yours or mine?

Comment: One last detail: some people prefer creating view models separate from domain models. That way they can put the select list in the view model and avoid passing it in via ViewData[...]. There are pros and cons but it is worth knowing about the options. It is of course simpler to show an example with ViewData so that is why I used it here.