# What does the EnumDataType attribute do in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I've been using `string` properties on some of my model objects to represent enums. I'm only using strings because there is not yet enum support in Entity Framework Code First. Anyway, I noticed that there is an attribute in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` called `EnumDataType`. I tried setting this attribute, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

I should mention that my ultimate goal is to have the appropriate drop-down list appear for any enum type in a "create" or "edit" view. I thought maybe `EnumDataType` would make this easier in an auto-scaffolding scenario, but I'm not sure this is the case.

**Three questions:**

1. Does `EnumDataType` have a purpose in ASP.NET MVC?
2. If yes, what does it do?
3. Do I need my model properties to be `int` (instead of `string`) to take advantage of `EnumDataType`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`EnumDataType` is currently supported only by ASP.NET Dynamic Data sites (in .NET 4.0). You can generally build your own custom HTML helper which will take the property check if it contains the attribute (by reflection) and creates drop down for it with values from the linked enum.

Comment: +1 and thanks. I was thinking I'd probably need a helper method. Do I need a helper method for each enum type or is it possible to write an all-purpose one that works for any enum type?

Comment: I believe it should be possible to write single method working for all enum types because enum type will be extracted from the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found for this was combining [this blog](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/05/21/entity-framework-4-1-supporting-enums/) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255108/590558). This makes both the view and model very readable and maintainable.

**See my [full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375647/590558)**.

Model:

```
public enum YesPartialNoEnum
{
    [Description("Yes definitely")]
    Yes,
    [Description("No way!")]
    No
}

//........

[Display(Name = "The label for my dropdown list")]
public virtual Nullable<YesPartialNoEnum> CuriousQuestion{ get; set; }

//........
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CuriousQuestion)
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC 3 does not have any logic to handle `EnumDataTypeAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Either MVC3 or EF4.1 CodeFirst appears to validate properties with this attribute.  Handy due to the lack of enum support in EF currently, meaning you can put the attribute on an integer property.