# Drop-Down List Enum ASP.NET MVC Using AttributeDescription Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Based on this post: [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc/694361#694361)

I want to do the exact same thing, except using the AttributeDescription field from my enum, for example:

```
[DescriptionAttribute("1 Star")] OneStar = 1,
[DescriptionAttribute("2 Stars")] TwoStar = 2,
[DescriptionAttribute("3 Stars")] ThreeStar = 3,
[DescriptionAttribute("4 Stars")] FourStar = 4
```

The solution given in the prior link will show "OneStar" in the text field of a drop down, whereas I'd want to see "1 Star".  I've seen a few posts relating to this, but their solutions are quite verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something among the lines:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumObj)
{
    var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
    var fields = enumType.GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public
    );
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<TEnum>();
    var items = 
        from value in values
        from field in fields
        let descriptionAttribute = field
            .GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true
            )
            .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault()
        let description = (descriptionAttribute != null)
            ? descriptionAttribute.Description 
            : value.ToString()
        where value.ToString() == field.Name
        select new { Id = value, Name = description };
    return new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
}
```

Comment: Instead of defaulting to value.ToString() when no Desc attr my version uses field.Name:  let description = (descriptionAttribute!=null)?descriptionAttribute.Description : field.Name.Replace("_", " ")

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found for this was combining [this blog](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/05/21/entity-framework-4-1-supporting-enums/) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255108/590558). This makes both the view and model very readable and maintainable.

**See my [full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8375647/590558)**.

Model:

```
public enum YesPartialNoEnum
{
    [Description("Yes definitely")]
    Yes,
    [Description("No way!")]
    No
}

//........

[Display(Name = "The label for my dropdown list")]
public virtual Nullable<YesPartialNoEnum> CuriousQuestion{ get; set; }

//........
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CuriousQuestion)
```