# Razor converting enum to int inside a view

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I a razor view .I have line like bleow

```
<option value='@{(Int16)PhoneType.Work}'>@PhoneType.Work</option>
```

This is an  option in a select list/dropdownlist
In this I have an enum PhoneType.
For text filed @PhoneType.Work works fine
but for value field @{(Int16)PhoneType.Work is not working

What can i do to get integer value of the enum at value field

Comment: Why don't you use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper?

Comment: By writing a helper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5961529/29407

Comment: Have you tried @{ ((Int16)PhoneType.Work) } ?

Answer (score 68):

This syntax should do the trick (note the () instead of {}):

```
<option value='@( (Int16) PhoneType.Work )'>@PhoneType.Work</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not have another field on your viewModel that is an integer

```
public WorkId {get {return (int)Work; }
```

and use this in your view

```
<option value='@PhoneType.WorkId'>@PhoneType.Work</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use ChangeType function as below. Hope this helps for someone in future.

```
<option value=@Convert.ChangeType(PhoneType.Work, PhoneType.Work.GetTypeCode())>@PhoneType.Work</option>
```

or

```
<option value=@Convert.ChangeType(PhoneType.Work, typeof(int))>@PhoneType.Work</option>
```