# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Html.DropDownList for Enumerated values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm trying to display some options in a drop down list. The options will mimic values in an enum. The enum has the following three values:

```
public enum Gender 
{
  Male = 0,
  Female = 1,
  NotSpecified=-1
}
```

I am trying to generate the following HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Male</option>
  <option value="1">Female</option>
  <option value="2">Not Specified</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to do this with Razor, but i'm a bit lost. Currently I have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", WHAT GOES HERE?)
```

Please note, I cannot edit the enum. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

something like this...

```
//add this to your view model
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> genders = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))
    .Cast<Gender>()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.ToString(),
        Value = x.ToString()
    }); 

@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", Model.genders)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

The accepted answer has an extension method to convert the enum into a selectlist, which can be used like this

In the controller

```
ViewBag.Relationships = Gender.ToSelectList();
```

in the partial

```
@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", ViewBag.Relationships)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", Model.GenderSelectList);
```

However, I would rather use `DropDownListFor` to avoid using magic strings:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.relationshipDropDownList, Model.GenderSelectList);
```

and in the `ViewModel` you'd build your `SelectListItems`

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GenderSelectList
{
    get
    {
        List<SelectListItem> genders = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (Gender gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
        {
            genders.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = gender.ToString(), Value = gender.ToString("D"), Selected = false });
        }

        return genders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public enum EnumGender
    {
        Male = 0,
        Female = 1,
        NotSpecified = -1
    }


@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", (from EnumGender e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumGender))
                                                               select new SelectListItem { Value = ((int)e).ToString(), Text = e.ToString() }), "select", new { @style = "" })



//or

@Html.DropDownList("relationshipDropDownList", (from EnumGender e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumGender))
                                                               select new SelectListItem { Value = ((int)e).ToString(), Text = e.ToString() }), null, new { @style = "" })
```