# Custom html helpers in MVC 4

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-mvc-4

I created the helper class

```
namespace SEM.API.Helpers
{
    public static class Navigation
    {
        public static string BuildSomething(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            return "empty";
        }
    }
}
```

And added the namespace to webconfig `<add namespace="SEM.API.Helpers" />`
but I still getting an error:

> CS1061: "System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper"

It isn't solved after a lot of rebuilds

Comment: `BuildSomeShit` :) That's a good way to piss off a moderator...  I'd change it if I were you- Other users may perceive you as someone who hates your work.

Comment: Or other users may perceive it as hilarious, as I just did even though I'm late to the party (I thankfully had Zasz's comment to preserve the history and give me my lol).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> and added namespace to webconfig `<add namespace="SEM.API.Helpers" />`

Make sure you did this in `~/Views/web.config` and not in `~/web.config`.

Another thing to try is to add the `@using` directive to your view:

```
@using SEM.API.Helpers
@Html.BuildSomething()
```

Comment: oh, thanks! I added namespace to the wrong web.config :) now it works

Comment: I had to do both.. Add to ~/Views/web.config *and* add an @using statement to my view.

Comment: Yeah. I also had to add the `@using` statement to the view, which is kind of annoying to explain to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should add to the `~/Areas/[Area name]Views/web.config` the same string if Areas used.