# MVC 4 Razor DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I have this model

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
```

I need the `status` to have 3 possible values only `{Waiting, Approved, Rejected}`

I want to use a strongly typed view. So what's the best way to do it? Shall I use

```
<select name="Status" id="Status">
            <option value="Waiting">Waiting</option>
            <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

I would like to use `Enum` for `status` preferably but anyway of doing it would be fine.

Comment: Add items to your DropDownList from code-behind like [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc) will help you use an `enum`

Comment: i think either you have to create lookup table or you create a collection which is @Max Zhukov suggest below you .

Comment: [DropDown Bind in MVC 4 Razor View](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@{var listItems = new List<ListItem>
{
      new ListItem { Text = "Waiting", Value="Waiting" },
      new ListItem { Text = "Approved", Value="Approved" },
      new ListItem { Text = "Rejected", Value="Rejected" }
};
}
    @Html.DropDownList("Approved",new SelectList(listItems,"Value","Text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public enum Status
{
Waiting = 1,
Approved = 2,
Approved = 3
}

public Status Status { get; set; }

public IEnumerable GetStatus
{
get
{
return
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast().Select(p => new SelectListItem
{
Text = p.ToString(),
Value = p.ToString()
}).ToList();
}
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status,Model.GetStatus, “Select Status”)
```

Comment: Code only answers are deprecated. Please add some comment