# enum values in drop down list in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to create a dropdown list using enum value in mvc4

I have a class Language.cs

```
 public enum Language {
    English = 0
}
```

And my property is

```
public Language Language { get; set; }
```

How will i call in my view through a dropdown list

Comment: Hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 6):

You could have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Language SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages
    {
        get 
        {
            var languages = 
                from l in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Language))
                select new { ID = (int)d, Name = d.ToString() };
            return new SelectList(languages , "ID", "Name", this.SelectedLanguage);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedLanguage, Model.Languages)
```

Another possibility is to write a custom helper that will encapsulate this logic as shown in [`this blog post`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
public enum Language
{
    English,
    French,
    Spanish
}

public static class Enum
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
    {
        return System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public Language Language
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Languages
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetItems<Language>().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
@model ViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Language, Model.Languages)
```