# How to create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the Html.DropDownList extension method but can't figure out how to use it with an enumeration.

My classes :

```
namespace Support_A_Tree.Models
{
    public enum Countries
    {
        Belgium,
        Netherlands,
        France,
        United_Kingdom,
        Other
    }


    [MetadataType(typeof(SupporterMetaData))]
    public partial class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Countries Country { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> allCountries()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> choices = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (String c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries)))
            {
                choices.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = c , Value = bool.TrueString });
            }
            return choices;
        }


    }

    public class SupporterMetaData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Countries Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my VIEW I tried to get all countries, but it seems like i'm doing it wrong.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <p style = "color: red;">@ViewBag.Message</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2> You want to ... </h2>
        <p>Plant trees</p>
        @Html.CheckBoxSimple("support", new { @value = "Plant trees" })

        <p>Support us financial</p>
        @Html.CheckBoxSimple("support", new { @value = "Support financial" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Continue ">
}
```

Comment: Use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280906/binding-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4/17281798

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your view you can use [SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

E.g:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Countries)
```

given that the `@model` of the view has a property named `Countries` that is an `enum` type.

If you want to show a default text in the drop down (like: "Select country"). Take a look at the following question and answer.

[Html.EnumDropdownListFor: Showing a default text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21882471/5233410)