# Populate SelectList in ASP.NET MVC with enum

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, selectlist

I have an enumeration in my Data layer and I want to use its drop down list in my website project.
My enum in Data layer is:

```
namespace SME.DAL.Entities.Enums
{
    public enum EntityState
    {
        Open,
        Freezed,
        Canceled,
        Completed,
        Terminated,
        ReadOnly
    }
}
```

How can I make its select list and use it in my website's page?
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: The way I see it, you have 3 options: create a `SelectList` in your Action and pass it to the view **or** create a custom Html helper to do that **or** create a template for `Enum` in which you dynamically create the dropdown. The links posted in the answers bellow provide all the information needed to accomplish each of your options.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple example:

Controller:

```
public ViewResult SomeFilterAction()
{      
var EntityState = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(EntityState)).Cast<EntityState>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = v.ToString(),
             Value = ((int)v).ToString()
         }).ToList(),"Value","Text");
return View(EntityState)
}
```

View:

```
  @model System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
  @Html.DropDownList("selectedEntityState",Model)
```

Comment: If you move this logic inside a Html helper or even a template, you don't have to explicitly call the action every time your need an "enum dropdown".

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you were using MVC 5.1, they recently added a helper to create dropdowns from Enums.  However, since you're using MVC 4 you will have to hack something together.

There are some examples out there, and this has been answered many times already on this site if you had searched for it.

[How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)