# Access enum value on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement, enums

I have a enum for a field status as

```
  public status? Status { get; set; }
```

and the class as

```
 public enum status
    {
        Incomplete = 0,
        InReview,
        Live,
        Rejected,
        Suspended,
        Scheduled,
        Delisted
    }
```

And  in my model i populate my view using

```
var listStatus = new List<SelectListItem>();
listStatus.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "Incomplete", Value = "Incomplete" });
listStatus.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Ready for Review", Value = "InReview" });

            model.Status = listStatus;
     //above are in controller to initialise z model's list
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Status { get; set; }
    public status selectedStatus { get; set; }
```

In view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedStatus, Model.Status)
```

ISSUE ?

On submit of the form I want to verify the choice of the user to as to proceed
I mean I want to do something as

```
if(selectedStatus = "Incomplete")
{
//my codes hre
}
```

Question:

How do I access the Enum value matching the user's choice in the controller ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the solution that worked for me for future visitors.

```
            var  chosenStatus = model.selectedStatus;

            if (chosenStatus == status.Incomplete)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In Get action:

```
var statuses = from Status s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)) 
               select new { Id = (int)s, Name = s.ToString() };

ViewBag.Statuses = new SelectList(statuses, "Id", "Name", (int)Status.Live /*selected*/ );
```

In View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusId, ViewBag.Statuses as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select a status" )
```

And in Post action:

```
if(model.StatusId == (int)Status.InReview)
{
   // do your work..
}
```