# EnumDropDownList from a enum not in the passed model but in and external model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I have been looking around.
 I have a Model with an Enum, almost like a Helper to select from witch Column to search:

```
namespace Test.Models
{
    public class ViewEnums
    {
        public SearchParameter? searchParameter { get; set; }
    }

public enum SearchParameter
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
}
```

And a View :

```
    @using Test.Models;
    (...)
    Find :@Html.EnumDropDownListFor("SearchParameter",SearchParameter)
```

How can I get this EnumDropDownList to work? If it was in the model which was passed I could get it to work. But the Enum is in another Model.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Create a view model which includes all the models/properties you need

Comment: Tried to put the enum in the Main model and do:
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SearchParameter) but with no luck.

Comment: Got a part working using
`IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listSearchParameters = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchParameter)).Cast<SearchParameter>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString()
    }); ;
     @Html.DropDownList("SearchParameters", new SelectList(listSearchParameters, "Text"), "SearchParameter")`

Now I need to change the entry of my controller (SearchParameter) to String. Pitty I wanted to use the Enum type...

Comment: Are you using the `EnumDropDownListFor` method in MVC 5, or is this a custom helper? `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SearchParameter)` works.

Comment: I am using the EnumDropDownListFor method in MVC5, not a custom one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)