# Adding class to EditorFor in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show `Enum` in EditorFor. I use Editor Template for show it.(DropDownList).

I have malty `EditorFor` in view. I want to set class for some controls.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Position, new { @class = "smallinput", style = "width:150px !important" })
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DocumentType)
```

In Editor: Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Enum.cshtml

```
@model Enum
@{
   var values = Enum.GetValues(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType).Cast<object>()
                 .Select(v => new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Selected = v.Equals(Model),
                     Text = v.GetDisplayName(),
                     Value = v.ToString()
                 });
}
@Html.DropDownList("", values)
```

In Model

```
[DisplayName("نوع سند")]
[UIHint("Enum")]
public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
```

Comment: You need MVC 5 to use `@Html.EditorFor()` with html attributes. For MVC 4, you will need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or similar. Another alternative is pass the html attributes as `AdditionalViewData` and use a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: Thanks, I want to show enum in dropdown, so i use EditorFor.I use MVC4. I can use `AdditionalViewData` for pass class to editor?

Comment: You need to include the `EditorTemplate` you use to render the dropdown

Comment: I have a EditorTemplate and render dropdown, but how to pass class to EditorTemplate?

Comment: If you not going to show the code, how do you expect me to help?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - actually, you need MVC 5.1 for html attributes, this wasn't in 5.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the class name to the `EditorTemplate` using `AdditionalViewData`.

In the main view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DocumentType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "myclass" } })
```

and in the `EditorTemplate`

```
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, values, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

However including the logic for the `SelectList` in an `EditorTemplate` is not good practice. I would recommend your consider creating an extension method for generating the `SelectList` and then this `EditorTemplate` wont be required. [Refer this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc). And `Selected = v.Equals(Model),` is pointless because the `Selected` property will be ignored (the selected item will be the value of `DocumentType`)