# MVC .net textbox to texbox area (Razor)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a text box that I want to expand and add a few lines to make it a text area instead of a small box.

original code

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.emailBody)

<input type="submit" value="Send Mail" class="btn btn-default" />
```

I have found this on SOF, but it is not working and the field looks the same

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.emailBody, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 })
<input type="submit" value="Send Mail" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Can anyone suggest a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Add a `DataType.MultilineText` attribute to the property and `@Html.EditorFor()` will render a `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text" ../>`

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string emailBody { get; set; }
```

Note also (assuming your using MVC-5.1+), then to add html attributes, it should be

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.emailBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 } })
```

If you have only MVC-5, then use `@Html.TextAreaFor()` or create a custom `EditorTemplate` and pass the attributes as `AdditionalViewData` ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341031/adding-class-to-editorfor-in-mvc/27341257#27341257))

Comment: Thanks 4 a fast solution :-)

Comment: Note also (and I'm assuming your using MVC-5.1+) then to add the html attributes, it should be `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.emailBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 } })` otherwise you have to use `@Html.TextAreaFor()` or create a custom `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.emailBody, new { @rows = 3 })
```

you can use textarea for and set rows according to your choice its better way then increasing line of a normal textbox....

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use something like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.emailBody, new { @rows = 3 })
```

instead of EditorFor, you can use TextAreaFor to get multiple lines in a textbox