# Get Enum value to show on Dropdownlist Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum PaymentType
{
    Self=1,
    Insurer=2,
    PrivateCompany=3
}
```

And I am showing it as select box options like this inside Controller:

```
List<Patient.PaymentType> paymentTypeList =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof (Patient.PaymentType)).Cast<Patient.PaymentType>().ToList();
    ViewBag.PaymentType = new SelectList(paymentTypeList);
```

Here I can see that only the string part (example "Self") of the enum is going to the front end, so I won't get the value (example "1") of enum in my dropdown. How can I pass text as well as value of enum to select list?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to since the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind to the string value when you post back, but [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc) show some methods to do it.

Comment: Just cast it to the `int` it will give you the `int` value.

Comment: Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write an extension method like this:

```
 public static System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj)
            where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible // correct one
 {

   return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
              .Select(x =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), x),
                        Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString()
                    }), "Value", "Text");

}
```

and in action use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
     ViewBag.EnumList = PaymentType.Self.ToSelectList();

     return View();
}
```

and in View :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SomeProperty,ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)
```

### Rendered HTML:

```
<select id="EnumDropDown" name="EnumDropDown">
<option value="1">Self</option>
<option value="2">Insurer</option>
<option value="3">PrivateCompany</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [working Demo Fiddle of Enum binding with DropDownListFor](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t7GEzy)

Comment: please clarify how to use this extension. so that it will be useful for others too

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum PaymentType
{
        Self=1,
        Insurer=2,
        PrivateCompany=3
}
```

Get Self value:

```
int enumNumber = (int)PaymentType.Self; //enumNumber = 1
```

Exemple:

```
getEnum(PaymentType.Self);

private void getEnum(PaymentType t)
{
            string enumName = t.ToString();
            int enumNumber = (int)t;
            MessageBox.Show(enumName + ": " + enumNumber.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension method in MVC5 called [SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which will generate the drop down list for you and bind the response back to an enum property in your model.