# MVC DropDownListFor - SelectedItem not working for nested value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

In my C#, MVC4 .NET WebApplication I have a custom helper that has the following method-call:

```
@Custom.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategorySetups[categoryId].Gender, CategoryHelper.Genders, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

which is internally something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(expression, new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text"))
```

because I have an override of SelectListItem here.

This call is not selecting the value in the rendered view as stored in

```
m.CategorySetups[categoryId].Gender
```

If I call the method this way (not in the same view):

```
@Custom.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, CategoryHelper.Genders, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The rendered HTML has the correct value marked as

```
<option value="Under15" selected>Under15</option>
```

So my guess is, that is has something to do with nesting of the property that is selected but I don't see it.

From debugging I can see, that

```
m.CategorySetups[categoryId].Gender
```

has the correct value set when it should render the select.

**Note**: Not sure if this may causing the issue (because the second way it's working) but the bound values Type is Enum.

**Update as of comments:**

The implementation is as follows:

```
 public static readonly List<SelectListItem<ClassificationType>> ClassificationTypes = new List<SelectListItem<ClassificationType>>
        {
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = @"please select...", Value = ClassificationType.NotSet},
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = EnumParser.GetString(ClassificationType.Under13), Value = ClassificationType.Under13},
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = EnumParser.GetString(ClassificationType.Under15), Value = ClassificationType.Under15},
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = EnumParser.GetString(ClassificationType.Under18), Value = ClassificationType.Under18},
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = EnumParser.GetString(ClassificationType.Over30), Value = ClassificationType.Over30},
            new SelectListItem<ClassificationType> {Text = EnumParser.GetString(ClassificationType.Open), Value = ClassificationType.Open}
        };
```

Comment: what is the implementation ``CategoryHelper.Genders`` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) contructor has an [**overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which takes a parameter `object selectedValue`, you need to specifiy the selected value, In normal `DropDownListFor()` we do this way:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Gender,
                     new SelectList(Model.Genders,"Id","Value",Model.Gender),
                     new { @class = "form-control" })
```

### UPDATED:

In your case you can do this:

```
@Custom.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategorySetups[categoryId].Gender, 
                        new SelectList(CategoryHelper.Genders,"Value","Text",Model.CategorySetups[categoryId].Gender), 
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
```

One thing more, as you are populating items via `Enum`, you can use extension method I posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807472/get-enum-value-to-show-on-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc/28807644#28807644)

Comment: Any simple way to get the value from the expression? Otherwise I have to change the call(s) to @Custom.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, CategoryHelper.Genders, new { @class = "form-control" }) where I don't have the selectedValue parameter but the expression to the property

Comment: @KingKerosin you don't want to do with the second way?

Comment: I misread the answer... I made slight changes and it works now as expected. Thanks. Accepted!