# Unable to set default value for Html.DropDownList in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am showing an enum as dropdown list in my `Edit view` like this:

### Inside Model

```
public enum PaymentType
{
    Self=1,
    Insurer=2,
    PrivateCompany=3

}
public PaymentType PaymentTypeSelected { get; set; }
```

### Inside Controller

```
ViewBag.EnumList = Patient.PaymentType.Insurer.ToSelectList();
patient.PaymentTypeSelected=Patient.PaymentType.Insurer;
```

### In View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PaymentTypeSelected, 
    ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)
```

### And an Extension Function

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    return new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
           Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), x),
           Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString()
        }), "Value", "Text");
    }
```

### Generated HTML

```
<select data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="The PaymentTypeSelected field is required."
        id="ptype" name="PaymentTypeSelected">
    <option value="1">Self</option>
    <option value="2">Insurer</option>
    <option value="3">PrivateCompany</option>
</select>
```

It all looks okay to me, but the dropdown does not show default selected value (in my case `Insurer`). Can any one point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `ToSelectList()`?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the `value` attributes of the options are 1, 2 and 3 respectively and the property value evaluates to "Insurer". Try setting the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem` to the same as the `Name` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke tried not working

Comment: Can you copy the HTML generated for the dropdown?

Comment: Works for me (although I just simplified it to `ViewBag.EnumList = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(PaymentType)));`

Comment: Just a wild guess.  Try casting those "ints" to strings.

Comment: I mean => m.PaymentTypeSelected.ToString();

Comment: You still generating the options values as the "1", "2" and "3" value (they need to be "Self", "Insurer" and "PrivateCompany"

Comment: @StephenMuecke no I made that update for Ray Suelzer only.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have tried it as you said with value and text same. but it still not preselect anything :(

Comment: @Athul : Y dont you send the selected attribute with the option you want to be preselected?

Comment: Then there is something else relevant that you are telling us because `ViewBag.EnumList = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(PaymentType)));` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is [as a working DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rA5a6L).

In short, you need to make sure that both the `Value` property of each `SelectListItem` and the `PaymentTypeSelected` property are pulling from the same Enum conversion. You were doing `int` for the `Value` and `string` for the `PaymentTypeSelected`. Change your extension to this and you're golden.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj) 
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum))
                .OfType<Enum>()
                .Select(x => new { Text = x.ToString() })
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.Text, 
                    Value = x.Text
                });

        return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why, But THAT WORKED :D

Comment: Good answer, ToString should be sufficient though, don't think GetName is needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/694361/84206

Comment: @AaronLS Good call. Also, do you think the transparent identifier is overkill? While it's DRY it might be tough to read later.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I don't have a strong opinion either way,  It's tucked away inside the extension method.  Variations of this approach I've used do camel case splitting, and/or look for a Description attribute, when setting the `Text` field for nicer display, but that's a whole other tangent.

Answer (score 2):

**As Stephen pointed out, this won't work if you use the DropDownListFor, as the model binding prefers the `m=>m.SomeProperty` over the constructor parameter.**

You can use the SelectList constructor that takes a 4th object parameter to indicate the selected value:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx

```
// in controller we'll pass the desired selected value to extension method:
ViewBag.EnumList = Patient.PaymentType.Insurer.ToSelectList(Patient.PaymentType.Insurer);

// update method to support this parameter
public static System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum obj, object selectedValue)
        where TEnum : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible // correct one
    {
        return new SelectList(
            Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).OfType<Enum>()
                 .Select(x =>
                     new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), x),
                         Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToString()
                     }
                 ) 
            ,"Value", "Text"
            ,(int)selectedValue); // pass selected value to SelectList constructor

    }
```

I've made one edit to add `(int)`, which is somewhat of a dirty cast since we're coming from an `object`.  This of course can be improved upon.

Comment: This seems MUCH better than my answer. +1

Comment: The 4th parameter is ignored if your binding to a model property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right.  So much for MSDN documentation.

Comment: @AaronLS please add a code sample for  how you want to bind this to html.dropdown in the view

Comment: @Athul My intention was that you'd leave the view the same, but Stephen pointed out the problem.  I believe your problem is you cast your enums to ints `Value = (Convert.ToInt32(x))` but your model property is still an enum(thus it takes the ToString of the enum by default).  If you look at the HTML that would be generated by `Value = x.ToString()` instead then you'd see by default DropDownList uses the string representation of enums: http://stackoverflow.com/a/694361/84206

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => ((int)m.PaymentTypeSelected).ToString(), ViewBag.EnumList as SelectList)
```

Comment: Totally untested, just going off of memory here.  But cast the PaymentTypeSelected to an int and then to a string so that it will match the selectlist string values which are the enums casted to ints and then strings.

Comment: This won't work .Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: @RaySuelzer I think this approach just requires `(int)m.PaymentTypeSelected` no ToString needed.

Comment: Athul.. It's because my boxing is wrong.  Do this: `((int)m.PaymentTypeSelected).ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

A `SelectList` can takes 4 arguments, where the last argument `selectedValue` is an object of whatever type is in your list. So you can try like the following:

```
ViewBag.yourEnumList= new SelectList(enumList, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
```

Or, You can apply this in your extension function