# Enum to List<Object> (Id, Name)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, enums

What is the best practice to convert an `enum` to an list of Id/Name-objects?

`Enum`:

```
public enum Type
{
    Type1= 1,
    Type2= 2,
    Type3= 3,
    Type4= 4
}
```

`Object`:

```
public class TypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Something like:

```
var typeList = new List<TypeViewModel>();
foreach (Type type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type)))
{
    typeList.Add(new TypeViewModel(type.Id, type.Name));
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing it ?

Comment: I would like to use it in my MVC Razor-View like this: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeId, new SelectList(Model.AllTypes, "Id", "Name"))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You can just use : @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.EnumProp)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
var typeList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type))
               .Cast<Type>()
               .Select(t => new TypeViewModel
               {
                   Id = ((int)t),
                   Name = t.ToString()
               });
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have :

```
public enum Gender
{
   Male = 0,
   Female = 1
}
```

And model :

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FullName {get; set;}
   public Gender Gender {get; set;}
}
```

In view you can simply use :

```
@model YourNameSpaceWhereModelsAre.Person;

... 

@Html.BeginForm(...)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id);
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName);
   @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => Model.Gender);

   <input type="submit"/>
}
```

More information you can find or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: How is the selected Gender posted?

Comment: Well, you don't really need to think about it, it's where the magic of helper method comes. Just send model to view where one of its properties is enum, use `EnumDropDownListFor()` inside the form get the model back with submitted request to your `Post` method of controller and work with model.

Comment: I accepted S.Akbari's answer because I asked for a list, but your way seems the better way to do this in my case.

Comment: Well, if you work with older version of Asp.Net MVC then Abari's answer is the only way to go but in new versions i like this 'magic' helper methods that we can use.