# Creating checkboxes for an entity's List of enums in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

There is an entity that has `public List<DayOfWeek> DefaultDaysOfWeek`.

I want to bind this list to a set of 7 checkboxes respectively in the view.

I have not found a default way to do something similar to:
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DefaultDaysOfWeek, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

I have also tried the [CheckBoxList(For)](http://mvccbl.com/) framework.

I believe the reason none of this has worked is because I cannot access this enumeration in the View.

Comment: Do you mean radio buttons? (checkboxes would allow you to select multiple days, in which case you should consider you own enum with a `[Flags]` attribute)

Comment: I would like the user to be able to select multiple days. If I used [Flags] would I have two enums? (`DaysOfWeek` and `DaysOfWeekFlags`)

Comment: No, You would just have one - say `[Flags] public enum MyDayOfWeek { Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, Tuesday = 4, .... }` but it really depends on how you are persisting this information. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990786/how-to-reduce-code-duplication-in-asp-net-mvc-view-when-working-with-flags-enum/37991402#37991402) for an example of binding to an `enum` with a `FlagsAttribute`

Comment: So would I then change `public List<DayOfWeek> DefaultDaysOfWeek` to `public List<bool> DefaultDaysOfWeek`?

Comment: No, its just `public MyDayOfWeek DefaultDaysOfWeek { get; set; }`

Comment: The other alternatives are to use a view model with a `bool IsSelected` property (along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416), or you could just manually create `<input type="checkbox" name="DefaultDaysOfWeek" value="@DayOfWeek.Sunday" />` (one for each value)

Comment: Oh hey, that worked! Thanks so much!