# How is an int translated to which enums are selected?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, enums

A previous developer (who no longer works with us, so I can't ask him) has done something pretty slick, that I really do not understand.  We have this enum:

```
   [Flags]
    public enum SidingTypePreference
    {
        [Value(Name = "Vinyl")]
        Vinyl = 1,
        [Value(Name = "Metal or Aluminum")]
        MetalOrAluminum = 2,
        [Value(Name = "Composite")]
        Composite = 4,
        [Value(Name = "Wood")]
        Wood = 8,
        [Value(Name = "Other")]
        Other = 16
    }
```

In the database, `SidingTypes` is stored as a single int, which is a sum of all the values selected.

[image]

In the Model:

```
public SidingTypePreference? SidingTypes { get; set; }
```

In the controller, where `table` is just a row result from a query:

```
Model.SidingTypes = table.SidingTypes
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.SidingTypes, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", GroupID = "SidingTypePreference", Cols = 1 })
```

But, here's the part I don't understand. Let's say that `SidingTypes = 10`.  By some sort of voodoo magic, that int is translated into:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="..." name="SidingTypes_0" value="1">  Vinyl
<input type="checkbox" class="..." name="SidingTypes_1" value="2" checked>  Metal or Aluminum
<input type="checkbox" class="..." name="SidingTypes_2" value="4"> Composite
<input type="checkbox" class="..." name="SidingTypes_3" value="8" checked> Wood
<input type="checkbox" class="..." name="SidingTypes_4" value="16"> Other
```

*(class redacted just to prevent the need to scroll, but they are all 'lookup-checkbox-SidingTypes'.)*

From the value of that int, it knows which are checked and which are not.

**FIRST QUESTION:** Is this native .NET?  Or is there some extension method or template that I need to find?

**SECOND QUESTION:** What I need to do, independent of anything else, is to build a method to determine if an enum is selected.

Something like:

```
private bool IsSelected(int SidingTypes, SidingTypePreference sidingTypePreference)
{
  ... ?? ...
  return true or false;
}
```

Comment: Well, enums with the `Flags` attribute decompose a value into the equivalent bits that would make up that composite value (e.g. `10 = 2 + 8`)  I suspect there is a custom template in the project somewhere to convert the enum value into a set of checkboxes.

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx also this post has a very nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990786/how-to-reduce-code-duplication-in-asp-net-mvc-view-when-working-with-flags-enum/37991402#37991402) for working with enums with the `[Flags]` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this native .NET?

Part of it is.  Enums with the Flags attribute decompose a value into the equivalent bits that would make up that composite value (e.g. 10 = 2 + 8)

Converting that value into a set of checkboxes is not native.  I suspect there is a custom template in the project somewhere to convert the enum value into a set of checkboxes

> How do I determine if an enum is selected.

Just use bitwise operations:

```
private bool IsSelected(int SidingTypes, SidingTypePreference sidingTypePreference)
{
  return (SidingTypes & (int)sidingTypePreference) != 0;
}
```

Since the `&` operator will return a number with the bits that are "selected" in both `SidingTypes` and `sidingTypePreference`.  If no flags match, the result will be all zeros; so any number other than 0 indicates a match.

Comment: There's a method on Enum, HasFlag(Enum flag) method that does that check.

Comment: Ok thanks D Stanley.  But, one question. In your example above, I get: Operator '&' can not be applied to operands of type Int and SidingTypePrefrences

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I missed that you're checking an int versus an enum.  I added a cast to int to allow the operation.

Comment: @Fran True, but the input is an `int` not a `SidingTypePreference` so you'd have to cast the int value to an equivalent enum.  Plus there is some type-safety overhead with `HasFlag`.  Since we're already not type-safe that overhead is not necessary.

Comment: true.  I am doing an Enum.Parse() to put my int into a the flag values.

Answer (score 2):

Last I checked (a couple of years ago now), ASP.NET MVC didn't have a built-in template for flags enums like this. However, it's likely that the developer created a [custom editor template](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) to recognize this type (or maybe flag enums generally) and display an editor for it.

Check out the files in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/`--particularly ones named `SidingTypePreference.cshtml` or `Object.cshtml`. It might also help to do a full-text search for `lookup-checkbox-` anywhere in your project.

For your second question, D Stanley's answer is correct: you use a bitwise `&` operator against the value that you're interested in, and then check to see if the result is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you!!  And your hint to do a search for lookup-checkbox was spot on.  Found the template.

Comment: Also, I have to ask about your user name... StriplingWarrior.  Mind if I ask what that's from :-) ?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: There's an account in the Book of Mormon about a company of young soldiers who exhibited such faith that they received divine protection in battle. They're referred to as "stripling soldiers" in the scripture, but in modern LDS culture they're often referred to as [Stripling Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_thousand_stripling_warriors). "Stripling" just means "young." I adopted the username/email when I was younger and haven't bothered updating it as I age. :-)

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured :-) It caught my eye.  Go Armies of Helaman!