# How to set value for Html.EnumDropDownListFor in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, selected, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am not sure if this is duplicate, or either I am asking the right direction, still to be sure I thought why not asking the GURU's.

So I have this enum in my model

```
public enum LienRequirement
{
    AbstractJudgment=1,
    AbstractSupportJudgment=2,
    Affidavit=3,
    Agreement=4,
    AgriculturalExempt=5
}
```

And here is my Model:

```
public class AbstractJudgment
{
    [Key]
    public int AbstractJudgmentId { get; set; }
    public LienRequirement LienRequirementId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Reports")]
    [Display(Name = "Report")]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public virtual Reports Reports { get; set; }
}
```

I am using MVC 5 Controllers with views, using Entity Framework. So In my create view, I am getting a dropdown for the property *

> *LientRequirementID*

given in the screenshot below:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YoBm.jpg)

*

I simply want the

> Agreement

or perhaps any other options to be selected.

Comment: For the moment I have just thought of a simple solution, I have just hard coded: 
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The LienRequirementId field is required." id="LienRequirementId" name="LienRequirementId" type="hidden" value="1" />

Comment: What is the exact list of items you want in the drop down?

Comment: Are you trying to make this as a non-nullable field and the user has to select one of the following in this list?

Comment: Show the create `GET` action method code, so others can guide you fast.

Comment: @dev8989 the exact list is quite big, I have just used around  7 - 8 samples for example. I want a certain index to be selected that's it. say Assignment from the dropdown should be selected when the page is loaded[check the screenshot].

Comment: When you say you want a want a certain index to be selected, do you want it to be the same for everyone or like an update page that changes to previous selections?  Help me understand this.

Comment: @dev8989 no.. not same. It should be dynamic.

Comment: I'm still confused a bit.  What determines the default values then? Geolocation, log in, type of user,  explain some more. Show the GET method as well.   Do you always want Assignments no matter what selected?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc