# Get the Id of elected Item fro dropdownlistfor Using Enum in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to get the Id of a DropdownList into a model using Enum but I always get null inside the variable of the Model. Hier ist my Code.

Model:

```
public partial class Vehicule
{
    public int vehiculeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> paidTextID { get; set; }
}
```

the Enum Class

```
public class EnumClass
{
    public enum Paid
    {
        Yes = 1 ,
        No = 2  ,
        NotComplete= 3,
    }

}
```

and the View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.paid, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.paidTextID, Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumClass.Paid)).Cast<EnumClass.Paid>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }), new { style = "width: 500px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.paid)
        </div>
    </div>
```

The List is populated but when I select I till have null inside the paidTextID.

Please Help

Thx

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Your over complicating this. Just make your `paidTextID` typeof `Paid` and use the `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()` method

Comment: And your `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` make no sense - they are for a different property

Comment: If you dont have MVC-5, then refer [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try to do that this evening. But my Question ist. If I change the Type of paidTextID to paid, to wich data type does it correspond in entity framework. Because I have to save letter in my data base. For example String correspond to varchar what is about the enum Paid? Thx.

Comment: I tried to change paidTextID to Emum Paid like this:

public EnumClass.Paid paidTextID { get; set; }

but i'm getting an error while while getting data of the vehicule Model at this line :
Zeile 36:             var vehicules = await db.Vehicule.ToListAsync();

the error ist : "The entity type is not part of the model for the current context"

Comment: Hi Stephen,
I still need some help. I created an Enum inside my model like this:

`public Nullable<Paid> paidTextID { get; set; }`

and change the view to this

`DropDownListFor(model => model.paidTextID, Enum.GetValues(typeof(Paid)).Cast<Paid>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }), new { style = "width: 500px" })`

but still the paidTextId is null when I chose an Item. Please help