# Bind enum with dropdown mvc5

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, enums

I am working with `MVC 5` application, and have `Enum` like this.

```
public enum Status
{
        [Description("Submitted")]
        Submitted=1,

        [Description("Approved")]
        Approved=2,

        [Description("Rejected")]
        Rejected=3
}
```

Now want to bind it with the `DropDownList` directly(means don't want to go from any `C#` code, directly in `@Html.DropDownList`).

How it could be possible?

I am using `Enum` helper class also. Please guide me.

Comment: Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.EnumProperty, Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumtype)).Cast<enumtype>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() })) here enum type is your Status enum and EnumProperty is your class model property that you are want to bind with dropdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It giving me error like " 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have write this kind of syntex :

` @Html.DropDownList("Status", Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() })) `

Comment: try this @Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))), " Select", new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: It solve dropdown binding issue but now have another issue. Its not giving text-value combination in dropdown. dropdown not showing value.