# Difficulties with DropDownlist in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, enumdropdownlistfor

I'm struggling with dropdownlist tried several methods online and all failed will show the methods that I tried.

**Objective**
Create a Reciept with date,reference... & country. Country is Required and should be a dropdownlist.

So the Table for **Reciept**("ID, Name, Date, Address, City, CountryList).

*RecieptModel*

```
public class TransactionModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set; }
    public CountryList CountryList { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RecieptModel> Reciepts { get; set;}
    public DbSet<CountryList> coutryList { get; set; }
}
```

*CountryList*

```
public class CountryList
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    public enum Country
    {
        Germany,
        US,
        UK
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Date,City,CountryList")] Reciepts reciepts)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Reciepts.Add(reciepts);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(reciepts);
}
```

*View*

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryList, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CountryList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryList)
    </div>
</div>
```

This failed I looked for several examples I'm trying to do it without the use of javascript. In the End I just want to learn how to implement a Dropdownlist & save it to the database allot of the methods that I tried to implement failed in MVC5.

Comment: I'm not using any files I'm implementing I'm not using any external files or downloaded anything from nuget. What is the proper method to use a dropdownlist all the online materials use several methods. Some use IEnumerals but all fail

Comment: Define what "fail" means.

Comment: e.g. lets say I use public IENumerable CountryList where countrylist class contains ID, CountryName.    If I use @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryList, new SelectList(Model.CountryList)).   The error is Model.CountryList cannot convert from CountryList to IEnumerable

Comment: IEnumerable is not an enum.  An enum is a specific c# type

Comment: In your code above, change `public CountryList CountryList { get; set; }`
 to `public CountryList SelectedCountry { get; set; }` and then change your razor code to use `model => model.SelectedCountry` (also change the Bind attribute)

Comment: Yea I created something like IEnumerable CountryList CountryList{set; get;} & inside country list is the enum

Comment: Once again, IEnumerable is *NOT* an enum.  DO NOT use IEnumerable with EnumDropDownListFor.  What you're saying doesn't make any sense.  What do you mean "inside country list is the enum"?  An enum is already a collection of items, you wouldn't put it in another collection.

Comment: I had so many problems with cannot pass Models.CountryList to IEnumerables that I'm now just trying to find to use List. So same way just made CountryList SelectedCountry {get; set;}  also used Dropdownlist instead of enumDropDownList. In CountryList I used public List<string> country { get; set; } 
I still have the issue of cannot convert CountryList to ienumerable. I'm having problems with both enum and list way. should I just create the country list as a basic string forthe dropdownlist?

Comment: Now the probelm in Model.Country is System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.  Btw the database is populated with country names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugest you to add a html extension method that implement dropdownlist for a generic enumarator. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/694361).

Answer (score 0):

## There is slightly change in your view where you bind the Country

this is actually you write

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CountryList)
```

Change is need to add name property in your country list (it must be ID that is your taken in your model) , so it must be like this to maintain country list value

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryList.Id, new SelectList(model => model.CountryList)
```

Becouse every HTML control need unique indentifier