# Dropdownlistfor List<Model> in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm iterating through a list of my Student-viewmodel and creating DropDownLists for each student for their gender. The DownDownList renders fine, but the currently selected value isn't selected by default. *(Please read entire post, my problem only occours when using a List of the ViewModel).*

This is what I expect to be output:

[image: Expected]

But I get this

[image]

**ViewModel**

```
    public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectList { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

**The controller-code**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectLists = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
            selectLists.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = gender.ToString(), Value = gender.ToString() });

        List<Student> viewModel = new List<Student>();
        viewModel.Add(new Student() {Name = "Joe", Gender = Gender.Male, SelectList = new SelectList(selectLists, "Value", "Text") });
        viewModel.Add(new Student() {Name = "Jane", Gender = Gender.Female, SelectList = new SelectList(selectLists, "Value", "Text") });
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**View-code**

```
@using DropDownListDemo.Models;
@model List<Student>

<div class="row">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Label(item.Name)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(i => item.Gender)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(i => item.Gender, item.SelectList, "Select Gender")
    <br />
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

My initial post wasn't clear enough, so I'll elaborate a bit. The DropDownLists work just fine if i don't use a List of the ViewModel. Please take a look at this code below, which works just fine.

**Controller without multiple Students**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectLists = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Gender gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
            selectLists.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = gender.ToString(), Value = gender.ToString() });

        return View(new Student() { Name = "Jane", Gender = Gender.Female, SelectList = new SelectList(selectLists, "Value", "Text") });
    }
```

**View without multiple Students**

```
@using DropDownListDemo.Models;
@model Student
<div class="row">

@Html.Label(Model.Name)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Gender, Model.SelectList, "Select Gender")
</div>
```

Outputs as expected!

[image]

Comment: did you tried somthing obviosu like changing value to int value of enum?

Comment: not mention that question was already asked multiple times

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't find any answers. Would you mind posting a link?

Comment: first result of "dropdownlist binding enum in mvc" ... seriously, there should be some "googling" test before people post question on SO

Comment: Please read the edited part of my post. I'm sorry this caused you frustration <3

Comment: EditorTemplates that's what first result of "html.dropdownlistfor in foreach" returns

Comment: Thanks Selvin, that gives me a lead. I googled for things like "html.dropdownlistfor list" and "html.dropdownlistfor array" for quite a while, but yeah It's quite silly I couldn't find out for myself. Guess I got stuck in a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a dropdownlist from an enum in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Tassadaque, thank you, but please read the entire post. My issue isn’t with creating drop downs from enums.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DropdownListFor` will show the select list item that has a `Value` referencing the same object that is in the property that it is bound to i.e. `Student.Gender` in your case.

When you create your select list items, you are doing `Value = gender.ToString()`, but gender.ToString() != gender.

Try setting value as just `Value = gender` which I would imagine would work, as it would use the int value referenced by the enum.

Alternatively, change your `Student.Gender` property to be `string`.

Comment: Thanks, but code works fine as long as I'm not using a collection of the ViewModel, so the referencing shouldn't be off, or am I missing something? Neither changing the value to the int-value of gender, nor setting the Student.Gender-property to string fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I've found the following workaround, which still doesn't answer my initial question, but it works just as good in my case - though it still bothers me that I didn't get any closure to *WHY* the previous code didn't work.

When initializing the SelectList we can pass in a fourth parameter: selectedValue.

```
viewModel.Add(new Student() { Name = "Joe", Gender = Gender.Male, SelectList = new SelectList(selectLists, "Value", "Text", Gender.Male) });
```