# How to display different name for properties in enum class in @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Lets say I have the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
   public class InputParametersModel
   {        
      public Variable Xvariable { get; set; }

      public Variable Yvariable { get; set; }
   }

    public enum Variable
    {
        [Display(Name = "A A")]
        aa,
        [Display(Name = "B B")]
        bb,
        [Display(Name = "C C")]
        cc,
    }
}
```

and my view has:

```
@model MyProject.Models.InputParametersModel
@using MyProject.Models

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Xvariable, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Variable))), "Select", new { @class = "form-control"})
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Yvariable, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Variable))), "Select", new { @class = "form-control"})
}
</div>
```

How do I get the dropdowns to display "A A", "B B" and "C C"? I thought adding `[Display(Name = "A A")]` would solve my problem but it's still displaying 'aa' etc.

*(this just a snippet of the code but hopefully I accounted for any syntax errors)*

*Edit: forgot to copy* `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: which version of .Net are you using? (.net core or .net fw)

Comment: It's .net core if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show display names using `Html.GetEnumSelectList` in .Net Core

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Xvariable,Html.GetEnumSelectList<Variable>(),
                                    new { @class = "form-control" })

//Or

<select asp-for="Xvariable" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Variable>()">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```