# Generic Enum string value parser in c#?

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration, text-parsing

I have a weird question about parsing enumerations from strings. As it is, my app needs to handle parsing of few enumerations from a config file. However, I don't want to write parsing routines for each enumeration type (as there are many).

The problem I am facing is that the following code is showing some weird error - The type of T has to be a non-nullable value type or something of the sort. I thought that enums are by default non-nullable?

If I restrict the type of `T` using `where T : enum`, everything else inside the method body (other than the `if Enum.TryParse` statement) is underlined as error.

Can anyone help with this weird minuscule issue?

Thanks,
Martin

```
public static T GetConfigEnumValue<T>(NameValueCollection config,
                                      string configKey, 
                                      T defaultValue) // where T : enum ?
{
    if (config == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    if (config[configKey] == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    T result = defaultValue;
    string configValue = config[configKey].Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValue))
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    //Gives me an Error - T has to be a non nullable value type?
    if( ! Enum.TryParse<T>(configValue, out result) )
    {
        result = defaultValue;
    }

    //Gives me the same error:
    //if( ! Enum.TryParse<typeof(T)>(configValue, out result) )  ...

    return result;
}
```

A user requested to post the text of the error (it is at code time, not compile/runtime), so here it goes:

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter TEnum in the generic type or method 'System.Enum.TryParse(string, out TEnum)'

Comment: Can you attach the error? without the where condition, it looks like your code should work.

Comment: @jdv-Jan de Vaan so does this work? I mean i know enum's are really ints and ints are of type System.Int32 struct... but does it really work?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811042/adding-constraints-for-nullable-enum, it might help.

Comment: @bleep: An enum can derive from any integral type (`byte`, `long`, etc.).

Comment: @bleepzter: Now that you added the error message, I see confirmed that this is the solution. So in retrospect I should have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static T GetConfigEnumValue<T>(NameValueCollection config, string configKey, T defaultValue)
{
    if (config == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    if (config[configKey] == null)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    T result = defaultValue;
    string configValue = config[configKey].Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configValue))
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    try
    {
        result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), configValue, true);
    }
    catch
    {
        result = defaultValue;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, with that information in mind, I see what the `Enum.TryParse` method is complaining about.

put a generic constraint on the method like so:

```
public static T GetConfigEnumValue<T>(NameValueCollection config, 
                                      string configKey, 
                                      T defaultValue) // where T : ValueType
```

Or just place the same constraint that is on the `Enum.TryParse` method.

```
where T : struct, new()
```

you can find this definition here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

Comment: Note that `where T : ValueType` doesn't work, `ValueType` is nullable, it has to be a `where T : struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# won't let you do `where T : enum`, you have to use `where T : struct`.

Note that there are ways around that restriction as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347386/generic-enum-string-value-parser-in-c/6347405#6347405) suggested.