# How to elegantly compare an enum to a DataTable cell?

Tags: c#, enums, coding-style, casting, comparison

In our application we work with `DataTable`s a lot. This is dictated by the interface to a another system. Often a column in one of these DataTable's is in fact an enumeration, which is then of a `Int16` datatype. Currently we use magic constants all over the place, but that isn't pretty. A real enum would be much better, but how can you write an elegant comparison? Especially considering that a `DBNull` is also sometimes a valid value.

Ideally we would write this:

```
if ( tbl.Rows[0]["EnumColumn"] == MyEnum.SomeValue )
    // Do stuff
```

But, naturally, that will not work. The closest to what I can come is:

```
if ( tbl.Rows[0]["EnumColumn"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows[0]["EnumColumn") == (int)MyEnum.SomeValue )
    // DO stuff
```

Which looks plain ugly. Any ideas on how to make this prettier and easier to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

`tbl.Rows[0]["EnumColumn"] != DbNull.Value && Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows[0]["EnumColumn"]) == MyEnum.SomeValue`

I would make a static method for it:

```
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2
    }

    public static bool EqualsTestEnum(object value, TestEnum enumValue)
    {
        if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i))
        {
            return i == (int) enumValue;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Will throw an exception on `DBNull`. Oh, sorry, my example had a mistake about this. Fixed.

Comment: I think this new code will work better. I actually would love to use a generic, but it doesn't seem to work in my compiler :(

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Comment: @Vilx In our framework we use something that converts values to enums. Every enum has a None value, so we know that a conversion didn't work (we don't like to use tryparse and out).

Comment: I guess that a static method is the best anyway. OK, I'll go with that.