# Generic C# method taking where the enum value as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Given a generic method that only operates on enum values

```
static void <T> method(T enum) where T ?????
{
     // do something with enum...
}
```

How do I constrain `T` such that only enum values are accepted? I've tried using `struct` however this disallows the use calling my method with a nullable enum type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic constraints on enum types are impossible in C#, but are possible in IL. Have a look at Jon Skeet's project, [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/), it will allow you to constraint your generic methods to enums.

Comment: Thats an example of how to do this using IL rather than a library to let you do this yourself, but very interesting all the same!

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can't. For some reason I don't know the C# specification explicitly forbids `System.Enum` as a constraint.

And even then it wouldn't accept nullable enums because nullable enums are no enums.