# Can I make this function that parses a list of enum names generic?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Non Generic Version (works):

```
    eTargets ParseTargets(string input)
    {
        eTargets targets = eTargets.None;
        string[] items = input.Split(',');
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            eTargets target;
            if (Enum.TryParse(item, out target))
            {
                targets |= target;
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.LogError("invalid target: " + item);
            }
        }
        return targets;
    }
```

Attempt at generic version (does not compile):

```
    T ParseNames<T>(string delimitedNames) where T : struct
    {
        T result = default(T);
        foreach (var name in delimitedNames.Split(','))
        {
            T parsed;
            if (Enum.TryParse<T>(name, out parsed)) 
                result |= (int)parsed; // ERROR: cannot convert T to int
                // result |= parsed --> operator |= cannot be applied to T and int
        }
        return (T)result;
    }
```

If the answer is "no", it would be helpful to understand the underlying limitation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum for some ideas.

Comment: seems like you downvoted my response as well.. I am going to delete my entry..

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
T ParseNames<T>(string delimitedNames) where T : struct //, Enum
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), delimitedNames);   
}
```

Your code already implies a 1, 2, 4, 8 numbering so the only 'gap' here is the requirement for the `[Flags]` attribute

Comment: `Enum` is not a valid constraint on a type parameter.

Comment: yea, I fixed it in my question - sorry about that

Comment: @Henk, yes the base 2 thing is implied, i should rename it ParseFlags

Comment: you are telling me it's a built in feature that i'm trying to re-write here?

Comment: @Gabriel I just learned that as well, but yes: `The value parameter contains the string representation of an enumeration member's underlying value or named constant, or a list of named constants delimited by commas (,). One or more blank spaces can precede or follow each value, name, or comma in value. If value is a list, the return value is the value of the specified names combined with a bitwise OR operation.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, I was wondering if this was 'just for fun' or that you missed it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
static T ParseNames<T>(string delimitedNames) where T : struct
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (var name in delimitedNames.Split(','))
    {
        result |= (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name);
    }
    return (T)(object)result;
}
```

Comment: that results in the same error as using no cast: "operator |= cannot be applied to T and int"

Comment: @Gabriel: fixed. Since `Enum.TryParse` doesn't exist in .NET 3.5, I wasn't able to test it, but you can easily modify this to your needs.

Comment: Apologies Groo, the down-vote was not intentional! Didn't initially realise I'd clicked it.