# Best way to implement fluent extension on the enum member

Tags: c#, methods, enums, fluent

Lets say I got the extension which does something with the enum and then just returns it.

```
public static T Do<T>(this Enum e) where T : struct
{
    // Do something.
    return // e? .. (T)e? .. or (T)(object)e? ;
}
```

So what should I return to let my code be successefully built and run with this example:

```
Roles role = Roles.Admin | Roles.Moderator;
role.Do<Roles>().SomethingElse().AndMore<Roles>().Etc<int>();
```

__

```
return (T)e;
```

http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1349685696025173.png

__

```
return e;
```

http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/1349685753912110.png

__

```
return (T)(object)e;
```

Actually works, but does boxing and then unboxing.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Adding more extension methods should not be the problem.

Comment: How is the `SomethingElse` method defined? What type does it expect to operate upon?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that's not the point. The point is in the `Do` method.

Comment: @AgentFire, of course that it is the point. You have to return the type that the next function in the chain expects.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have to return the type I have received as an input. So I am asking the best way to do that.

Comment: @AgentFire Then remove the generic parameter and return the enum type....

Comment: @AgentFire Just as a note, the `Enum` *class* will cause boxing of arguments in your sample above. There isn't an easy way to get constraints on `enum` types, but [Jon Skeet has some code exploring the area](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/).

Comment: @FelixK. in that case I will lose the desirable return type (`Roles` or whatever).

Comment: Just for your information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static T Do<T>(this Enum e) where T : struct
    {
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(e, typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: Still, boxing **and** then unboxing.

Comment: @AgentFire The boxing will occur because of your use of `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one due to the fact that you can't place an Enum constraint on a generic.

Have a look at this article for more, and a possible workaround:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to obey the mathematical construct of Closure.
Wikipedia explaines this well: [Closrue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28mathematics%29)

In a short sentence:
In your case you have to return what your next functions exprects as input parameter.