# Method to take in any Enum

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

is it possible to create a generic method that takes in any enum?  I'll then check the incoming type to first make sure it's an enum that was passed (or can I enforce that natrually through the method definition?) and second then if it's an enum, I will have a bunch of case statements that do stuff based on what type of enum that was passed.  So for example I can pass it CompanyColumns, PayColumns, etc. which are enums.  My method needs to be able to take any enum like this and allow me to then work with the enum in my internal case statement.

public static DbType GetColumnDataType(I want to be able to pass in any object that's an enum)

Comment: Seems like it would be easier and more orderly to overload the method by the parameter type.

Comment: well I'm trying to reduce code....and I have a reason I want to do it this way...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static void MyFunction<T>(T en) where T: IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("en must be enum type");
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: thanks.  And so if I want to work with the enum in a case statement I tried doing this, not sure how switch ((enum)T)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
public static DbType GetColumnDataType(Enum en){...}
```

that's not generic, but well work.

if you want generic you could do the following:

```
public DbType GetColumnDataType<T>(T en)
{
    Type t = n.getType();
    if (!t.isEnum)
    {
      //through exception 
    }
}
```

Comment: so you're not inheriting from IComparable, etc.? Just wondering why not...