# Why it is better to check type of T in generic class in static constructor instead of in non-static?

Tags: c#, generics

My consideration about that is why anybody would prefer doing it in static constructor which is called exactly once if the given type is incorrect in all calls, not just once and I would excpect to get exceptions in all parts of code where wrong type is used.

This is example of what I mean:

```
internal sealed class GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum<T> {
    static GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum() {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }
    }
}
```

Why not just non-static constructor?

Comment: Can you share your code? Or at least an example?

Comment: Why would you want to check the type at all?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the check you want to perform? Maybe you can use generic type constraints instead.

Comment: I don't get it. If you have checked that the type satisfies your criteria, why would you recheck it again and again later?

Comment: sorry, I added example code

Comment: I think you misunderstood how static constructors work for generic classes. If you use `GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum<int>` and `GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum<string>`, those are two different classes and the static constructor will be executed once for each of them.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum which may be of some help.

Comment: @Ginosaji I understand that part, my question is about why I would prefer to get just one exception for code like `var foo1 = new GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum<int>(); var foo2 = new GenericTypeThatRequiresAnEnum<int>()`

Comment: @AndyNichols my question is not about constraints but about idea of static constructors itselves

Comment: @user1121956 You'd get `TypeInitializationException`s for both of them.

Comment: You should get a `TypeInitializationException` for `foo2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot use particular type at all if static constructor fails.
So, there is no point to check type argument everywhere.

```
 public class Test<T>
    {
        static Test()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
new Test<string>(); //throws TypeInitializationException
```

Comment: ok, we can say that it reduce execution time in that case but doesn't it make debugging harder as we don't get exact exception message?

Comment: yes, you will have exact exception message, but details will be in InnerException property. Also it is good to don't duplicate code