# How to make a default editor template for enums in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

We know that if we define a template for a base type, that template could serve also for the derived types (if any other template was not used to override it).

As we can't inherit an `Enum`, nor `enum`s are considered inherited from the `Enum`, so neither the `Enum.cshtml` template in the `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` will not be active for different custom enum properties of the objects, like this one:

```
public enum Role
{
    Admin,
    User,
    Guest
}
```

I already saw some answers on this topic for ASP in general, but I am wondering if in **MVC 4** there are some improvements on this subject?

PS. I mean *without* use any explicit template attribution (like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Role, "Enum")` or `[UIHint("Enum")]`)

PPS. I am novice in MVC, so I'll appreciate your simple answers.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking for.  So simply defining an Editor Template for Enum, i.e. Enum.cshtml, is insufficient?

Comment: apriori, is insufficient...

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired generated html from your enum ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

K. Scott Allen has a nice [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/04/working-with-enums-and-templates-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) about this.

Comment: Good article. But need to include `Nullable` enum model types

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 5, you can add a template to Views->Shared->EditorTemplates containing this code:

```
@model Enum
@{
    var optionLabel = ViewData["optionLabel"] as string;
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"];
}
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m, optionLabel, htmlAttributes)
```

Example usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyType, 
                new { 
                       htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" },
                       optionLabel = "Select" 
                    })
```

In MVC 4, you don't have the `EnumDropDownListFor` extension, but you could roll your own, which I did previously like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>
   (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, 
    string optionLabel = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    //This code is based on the blog - it's finding out if it nullable or not
    Type metaDataModelType = ModelMetadata
       .FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).ModelType;
    Type enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(metaDataModelType) ?? metaDataModelType;

    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enumerated type");  


    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>()
       .Select(e => new SelectListItem
               {
                  Text = e.GetDisplayName(),
                  Value = e.ToString(),
                  Selected = e.Equals(ModelMetadata
                     .FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model)
               });

    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(
        expression,
        items,
        optionLabel,
        htmlAttributes
        );
}
```

References:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also; there is:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Role, new { @class = ".." })
```

Role being the enum of course :)