# Replace underscores in enum with spaces in DisplayFor helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I have an enum OType as:

```
public enum OType
    {
        First_enum_option,
        Second_enum_option,
        None_of_the_above
    }
```

My model has an enum field EType of this type, which is displayed in the view as:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EType)
```

In the view, the option is displayed correctly. But I want to replace underscores with spaces. With normal strings, I usually do this with `Replace("_", " ")`

If I use: `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EType.ToString().Replace("_", " "))`, I get this System.InvalidOperationException with message:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension >array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I have thought of this solution:

```
<td>
    @{ 
         string str = item.EType.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
     }

    @str
</td>
```

This solves the problem. Is there any concise and elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Add a `[Display]` attribute to each value and then use extension methods as described in [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099834/how-to-get-the-display-name-attribute-of-an-enum-member-via-mvc-razor-code) and in the view use `@Model.EType.GetDisplayValue()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a default editor template for enums in MVC 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139326/how-to-make-a-default-editor-template-for-enums-in-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1):

Change your enums to:

```
public enum OType
    {
        [Display(Name = "First enum option")]
        First_enum_option,

        [Display(Name = "Second enum option")]
        Second_enum_option,

        [Display(Name = "None of the above")]
        None_of_the_above
    }
```

and use,

```
@Model.EType.GetDisplayValue()
```

in your view.

Comment: This is even better if you get the display name from a resource file, then it can be localised if necessary.

Comment: And what is `GetDisplayValue()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EType).ToString().Replace("_", " ")
```