# Is it possible to guarantee the value of what ToString for an enum will be?

Tags: c#, enumeration

The database I am working with currently has a varchar field, and in my code I want to map the potential values to a enumeration like:

```
public enum UserStatus
{
    Anonymous,
    Enrolled,
    SuperUser
}
```

At the database level for this column, there is a constrain on it where the value has to be:

```
ANONYMOUS
ENROLLED
SUPERUSER
```

Is it possible for me to do:

```
UserStatus.SuperUser.ToString()
```

And have that value be SUPERUSER, and this be consistant and not screw up down the road?

Comment: If you are in control of the codebase, then for sure you can ensure that.

Comment: [`ToUpperInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: You might not even need this. You don't specify your SQL dialect, but many of them are case-insensitive by default for text, meaning `'SuperUser'` would satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 7):

A better solution may be to take advantage of the [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public enum UserStatus
{
    [Description("ANONYMOUS")]
    Anonymous,
    [Description("ENROLLED")]
    Enrolled,
    [Description("SUPERUSER")]
    SuperUser
}
```

Then use something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class EnumExtenions
/// </summary>
public static class EnumExtenions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The e.</param>
    /// <returns>String.</returns>
    public static String GetDescription(this Enum e)
    {
        String enumAsString = e.ToString();
        Type type = e.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMember(enumAsString);
        if (members != null && members.Length > 0)
        {
            Object[] attributes = members[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                enumAsString = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
            }
        }
        return enumAsString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an enum from its description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEnum">The type of the T enum.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
    /// <returns>Matching enum value.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    public static TEnum GetFromDescription<TEnum>(String description)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible // http://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/298053
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(TEnum).GetFields())
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (attribute.Description == description)
                {
                    return (TEnum)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == description)
                {
                    return (TEnum)field.GetValue(null);
                }
            }
        }
        return default(TEnum);
    }
}
```

So now you're referencing `UserStatus.Anonymous.GetDescription()`.

Of course you could always make your own `DatabaseMapAttribute` (or what-have-you) and create your own extension methods. Then you can kill a reference to `System.ComponentModel`. Completely your call.

Comment: If you define it as `GetDescription()`, you have to call it as `GetDescription()` too, not as `ToDescription()` :)

Comment: @hvd: Good call. Still getting through a Monday. ;-)

Comment: Is this really better? Judging from the amount of code you'd have to maintain I'd prefer Habib's solution...

Comment: @PoByBolek One major advantage is that it will support strings that are not valid as C# identifiers.

Comment: @PoByBolek You wouldn't really have to maintain it as it is rather trivial code, more so due to the Generic part.

Comment: @PoByBolek: I guess it depends. As-is, it probably isn't any better. But if you did take it the extra step and made the methods more concise (e.g `ToDatabaseEnum`) it may be more readable. Also, this would be fine to work with spaces (if that ever became a concern).

Comment: Sure... But the OP's constraint was that the value has to be one of `ANONYMOUS`, `ENROLLED` or `SUPERUSER`. Just saying... ;)

Comment: It might be useful to support something like `EnumMemberAttribute` - at least it will make the transformation consistent with DCS.

Answer (score 6):

You can't override `ToString` for enums, instead you can create your own [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) like:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToUpperString(this UserStatus userStatus)
    {
        return userStatus.ToString().ToUpper();// OR .ToUpperInvariant 
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
string str = UserStatus.Anonymous.ToUpperString();
```

Comment: @user1361315, it is for culture-insensitive conversion to upper case. see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well I don't care about culture, it is just for the database so it shouldn't change by culture anyhow.  So use ToUpperInvariant then?

Comment: @user1361315, if culture is not an issue then you can use `ToUpper`.

Answer (score 1):

Enum.ToString supports [4 different formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'd go for:

```
UserStatus.SuperUser.ToString("G").ToUpper();
```

"G" ensures that it will try first to get the string representation of your enum.