# How to pass generic enum parameter to method?

Tags: c#, enums

```
public static string GetCustomerIssueStatus(this HtmlHelper html, byte number)
{
    return Enum.GetName(typeof(Shared.Enumerators.CustomerIssueStatus), number);
}
```

How could I create this extension method, to accept all enum types as parameter?

Comment: You want extension method over `Enum`?

Comment: `Enum` isn't supported as a generic type parameter. See [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum).