# Can I use generic T in an extension method?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Trying to mimic this post: [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum?rq=1)

```
public static string[] ToTextArray(this Dictionary<string, T> dictionary) where T:struct, IConvertible
{
    ...
}
```

It appears my `T` cannot be resolved. What is the correct way to write an extension method for all `Dictionary<string, enum_type>` classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the generic type parameter in the method declaration:

```
public static string[] ToTextArray<T>(this Dictionary<string, T> dictionary) 
  where T: struct, IConvertible
```

Comment: O my! I just need another pair of eyes to take a look at my code. Thank you.