# Trying to parse a flag enum to string

Tags: c#, parsing, generics, enums

I have a class "license" which is a collection of a bunch of enum flags like this:

```
Public class License
{
    UsageType Usage { get; set; }
    PlatformType Platform { get; set; }

    public enum UsageType { read = 1, write = 2, wipe = 4, all = 7 }
    public enum PlatformType { windows = 1, linux = 2, ios = 4, all = 7 }

    etc...
}
```

The point is that the various flags of the same category can be OR'd together to form a profile of what the user can do with said license. Now I'm trying to display the values of "Usage" and "Platform" in a human-friendly way so for instance if Usage == UsageType.read | UsageType.write then it should be parsed to "read, write".

I did this successfully with a single enum type by testing the value for each flag and appending enumitem.ToString() for each flag it has to a string. Since I have a lot of these enums and values though, I'd like to come up with a more generic approach.

I came up with this (below) but since I'm not very familiar with template functions in c# so I don't know why this doesn't work but at least it should illustrate what i mean:

```
private string parseEnum<T>(T value)
{
    string ret = "";
    foreach (var ei in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        if (value.HasFlag(ei)) ret += ei.ToString() + ", ";
    }
    ret = ret.substring(0, ret.Length-1);
    return ret;
}
```

It's saying that T does not contain a definition for "HasFlag" but how could it now that if it doesn't know what T is?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the problem you're encountering is essentially this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum. The solution provided to that question should get you where you need to be.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Comment: Have you tried `enumValue.ToString()`?

Comment: If you use the [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your enum, you get nice printing (that lists each constituent flag that is set) for free.

Comment: As an aside, [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) is a great method for preventing ugly string-building loops.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should use the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx), which causes the built-in `ToString` and `Enum.Parse` methods to work just the way you want. Also note that the convention is that flags enum names [should be plural](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx), so e.g. `UsageTypes` instead of `UsageType`.

```
[Flags]
public enum UsageTypes { Read = 1, Write = 2, Wipe = 4, All = 7 }
[Flags]
public enum PlatformTypes { Windows = 1, Linux = 2, iOs = 4, All = 7 }

var e1 = License.UsageTypes.Read | License.UsageTypes.Write;
var s = e1.ToString();
Debug.Assert(s == "Read, Write");
var e2 = (License.UsageTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(License.UsageTypes), s);
Debug.Assert(e1 == e2);
```

Comment: Talking about naming conventions, enum fields [should be in Pascal Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043).

Comment: Doesn't work if `e1 = License.UsageTypes.All` s == "All" not "Read, Write, Wipe"

Comment: I think that was Tim's intent, hence why he set the value of `All` to 7 instead of 8 (which would have made it a unique value, rather than cumulative). It represents the combination of the previous 3 options. `(UsageTypes.Read | UsageTypes.Write | UsageTypes.Wipe).ToString("F")` evaluates to `"All"`. If you want to always see the individual options selected, just remove `All` from the enum.

Answer (score 0):

OP wishes to display the enum in a human-friendly way. Tim's solution is good, but what if your enum is a bit more complex and you want to display something different from the enum value, e.g., "Read Teachers" for "ReadTeachers", or "iOS" for "IOS"?:

To achieve this, you can modify the enum definition to give each value a display name that you define, and then add some extra logic to read it:

```
public class License
{
    [Flags]
    public enum UsageTypes
    {
        [Display(Name = "Read Teachers")]
        ReadTeachers = 1, 
    
        [Display(Name = "Write Students")]
        WriteStudents = 2, 
    
        [Display(Name = "Delete Students")]
        DeleteStudents = 4, 
    
        [Display(Name = "All")]
        All = 7
    }

    // Converts the flag enum to a displayable list of values, comma-separated.
    public static string? GetUsageTypesForDisplay(UsageTypes usageTypes)
    {
        List<string> enumValues = new();

        foreach (var enumVal in Enum.GetValues<UsageTypes>().Where(e => usageTypes.HasFlag(e)))
            enumValues.Add(GetDisplayName(enumVal)!);

        return ListToCsv(enumValues);
    }

    // Gets the value of the display name attribute for a single enum value.
    public static string? GetDisplayName(Enum enumValue)
    {
        string enumName = enumValue.ToString();
        Type enumType = enumValue.GetType();
        var enumMember = enumType.GetMember(enumName).FirstOrDefault();
        string? enumDisplayName;

        DisplayAttribute? displayAttribute = enumMember.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();

        if (displayAttribute != null)
            enumDisplayName = displayAttribute.GetName();
        else
            enumDisplayName = enumName;

        return enumDisplayName;
    }

    // Converts a list of strings to comma-separated values.
    public static string? ListToCsv(List<string> inputList)
    {
        string? outputCsv = null;

        if (inputList != null)
        {
            outputCsv = string.Empty;

            if (inputList.Any())
            {
                foreach (string listItem in inputList)
                    outputCsv = string.Format("{0}{1}, ", outputCsv, listItem);

                outputCsv = outputCsv.TrimEnd();
                outputCsv = outputCsv.TrimEnd(',');
            }
        }

        return outputCsv;
    }
}
```

Some of the extra code is due to this being a flag enum. We loop through the values, get the corresponding display name for each value that appears in the enum, and add it to a list for display.

Given the above, you can now do this:

```
var e1 = License.UsageTypes.ReadTeachers | License.UsageTypes.WriteStudents;
string? s = License.GetUsageTypesForDisplay(e1);
Debug.Assert(s == "Read Teachers, Write Students");  // passes
```

Note: Tested in .NET 6.