# Base Class Enum Implemented Differently in Derived Classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

My scenario:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //And this is what is getting me
    //I want a "Type" enum
}
```

Then derived classes would have different enums that they would assign to Type.

```
public class AnimalEntity : EntityBase
{
    //Type would have an 'animal type' value: Land, Sea or Air
    //Implementation code would do something like:
    // myAnimal.Type = AnimalType.Land
}

public class PersonEntity : EntityBase
{
    //Type would have a 'person type' value: Doctor, Lawyer or Engineer
    //Implementation code would do something like:
    // myPerson.Type = PersonType.Lawyer
}

public class MonsterEntity : EntityBase
{
    //Type would have a 'monster type' value: Goblinoid, Undead 
}
```

So, the big question is what am I trying to do, right? I am trying to create a base repository class, which will return entities grouped by type. All my entities will have some kind of "type", and I want to create a generic "group by type".

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : EntityBase
{
     //Our common GetAsync, GetByIdAsync, and all our other CRUD

     //And then something like this:
    public IEnumerable<GroupedData<string, T>> GetGroupedByType(string searchTerm)
    {
        var entities =
            from s in DbSet
            where (searchTerm == null || s.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm))
            group s by s.Type into g
            select new GroupedData<string, T> { Key = g.Key.ToString(), Data = g };

        return (entities);
    }
}
```

When T is AnimalEntity, I would get groups Land, Sea and Air with the corresponding entities. For PersonEntity, I would get Doctor, Lawyer, Engineer groups.

If my approach/design is invalid or less than ideal, please let me know.

Comment: What's wrong with specifying the enum in the generic? `EntityBase<TEnum>` etc. I'm not sure I'd choose to do that myself to be honest, but it should still be possible. That said, I've no idea how you'd integrate that into the grouping. I personally would not style a design based on trying to feed generic code. I would design stuff simply then identify where common logic resides. For example, instead of making the enum change, why not have each derived repository implement the grouping function?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Unless I'm mistaken it looks like the goal is to have the typed enum of the derived class as a key. Jason, can you confirm this?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I am beginning to come around to your line of thinking. Trying to abstract the group by type may not be enough payoff for all the other hoops. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum (please pardon me) are kind of *second class* citizens so first thing you may think about will **not work**:

```
class EntityBase<T> where T : enum {
    public T Type { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile, you may then think to replace `enum` with a base class:

```
class EntityBase<T> where T : EntityTypeBase {
    public T Type { get; set; }
}
```

Implementing in `EntityTypeBase` everything you need to be comfortable with them (`==` and `!=` operators, `IConvertible` interface and other boilerplate). It's a lot of code and you'll need also to manage that in EF (otherwise you won't be able to use such property in your queries unless you load everything in memory as objects). You may also [*force* the use of `enum`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum) (with a run-time check) but this will break SQL code generation in EF.

What's I'd suggest *in this case* is to use a type EF knows and understand. You may use a string (if you wish so) or an integer (as in this example):

```
class EntityBase
    public virtual int Type { get; set; }
}
```

In a derived class:

```
class AnimalEntity : EntityBase {
    public override int Type { 
        get { return base.Type; }
        set {
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AnimalType), value))
                throw new ArgumentException();

            base.Type = (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you still can use `PersonType.Layer` and `AnimalType.Land` keeping also a little of type safety. Of course you need to keep your enums in-sync to do not have duplicated values (otherwise `group by` won't work).

As last please also consider to use...another entity. If you have another table `EntityType`:

```
ID    Name          ApplicableTo
0     Laywer        Person
1     Programmer    Person
2     Land          Animal
...
```

What you have to do in the setter is to check if type is applicable or not and you may have few convenience classes that will group them by type:

```
public static class PersonType {
    public static EntityType Lawyer { get { ... } }
    public static EntityType Programmer { get { ... } }
}
```

IMO this is **scale better** (easier to add new items and you can delegate, in future, some behavior to `EntityType` items) and **it is safer** than hard-coded constants (because integrity is granted by DB engine itself). Of course price to pay is extra overhead for the search in the `EntityType` table (unless you use some caching mechanism).

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, it's not always useful but sometimes I'd like to see it!

Comment: Yes, +1 anyway. It isn't your fault ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman LOL we should blame Eric for that (actually I wonder if he ever wrote something about _"how we would use generics and why we can't"_).

Comment: where T : enum - doesn't work. Yep.
...and then, but this will break SQL code generation in EF.

You covered all the bases and pain points I have been banging my head against. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Jason yes, unfortunately in `where T : U` (where `U` isn't a _special case_ like `default`, `class`, `new` or `struct`) it must be a base class or an interface. Value types (then `enum`) are out of the game. Actually you may use a base class and write some code to instruct EF to use it but...well does it worth enough? BTW note that with strings as suggested by Patrick you have an easier life (of course price to pay is DB overhead and harder run-time checks) so you may also consider to use them.

Comment: @Jason see update answer, there is also a more DB-oriented solution (in case requirements will grow-up IMO it's better than compile time constants).

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

First, preferably, use a [generic type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) (`T` in this sample):

```
public class EntityBase<T>
{
   public T Type {get;set;}
}
```

Supply that type in the type declaration:

```
public class AnimalEntity : EntityBase<AnimalEnum>
{ }
```

Second, if you need more freedom, I usually use a list of `string` contants:

```
public class EntityBase
{
   public string Type {get;set;}
}

public static class AnimalTypes
{
    public const string Dog = "dog";
    public const string Cat = "cat";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had thought of those, but was hoping for something even cleaner.