# Enum flags wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I am refactoring some code for several enum collections that support the [Flags] attribute.

I am trying to come up with a generic class that allows for common methods (adding, removing and checking enums exist in the collection etc).

I began with this code:

```
public class EnumFlags<T>
{
    protected T collection;

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        this.collection = this.collection | value;
    }
}
```

However, I cannot use the | operator on type T.  I cannot add a constraint for T to be an enum (`where T : Enum` is not allowed).

Any ideas to approaching this problem?

Comment: See my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody) project - in this case, you'd want `Flags.Or`. (Also available as a nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnconstrainedMelody/)

Comment: @Jodrell - yes, now corrected.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/659190

Comment: This seems like a sin to me and there must be a better way so I'm not going to answer with it, but this works: `this.collection = (T)(object)((int)(object)this.collection | (int)(object)value);`

Comment: @DavidSherret That is one of C#s dark secrets, if you have a cast the compiler won't accept you can always use the black magic of casting to an object as a go between.

Comment: @Jodrell @abatishchev I don't think this question is a duplicate of the referenced question. The main problem is the line `this.collection = this.collection | value;` and adding the constraint `where T : struct, IConvertible` doesn't solve that problem. Maybe there's something in those answers that you could reference specifically that solves this issue? If not, I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: I will have to spend some more time on a possible solution.  Jon Skeet's project looks promising but may need to adapt it.  As for the marked duplicate - I am struggling to use generics for the operators (and `HasFlag` method).  I had one hack where I was using `Convert.ToInt64` but basically lost the generic <T> completely.  Also, I am unsure how to convert this int back to the Enum.  Not sure that was the best approach as I was casting throughout.

Comment: For anyone still wondering, here is a working implementation: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133407/Using-a-Generic-Type-to-Simplify-Flags-Enumeration


They solved it like this:
int flag = Convert.ToInt32(value);
_register = (_register | flag);
return this.State;