# How to pass a generic Enum as dictionary key in method parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

I'm trying to create a method that counts the number of times a given Enum occurs within some existing dictionaries for reporting purposes:

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> CountEnumOccurrence(Dictionary<Enum, List<string>> valueSource)
{
    var convertedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var entry in valueSource)
    {
        var name = Enum.GetName(entry.Key.GetType(), entry.Key);
        convertedDictionary.Add(name, entry.Value.Count);
    }

    return convertedDictionary;
}
```

However, if I attempt to call this method like so:

```
var criticalFailureCounts = CountEnumOccurrence(reportSpan.criticalFailures));
```

I get

> "cannot convert from '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Reporter.CriticalFailureCategory,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Enum,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`'"

Even though Reporter.CriticalFailureCategory is an Enum. I'm obviously doing this the wrong way, but I feel like there should be some way to achieve it.

Here's the definition for Reporter.CriticalFailureCategory at present:

```
namespace Reporter
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public enum CriticalFailureCategory
    {
        [EnumMember]
        ExcessiveFailures,
        [EnumMember]
        StalledInConfiguration
    }
}
```

The idea is that this can be expanded indefinitely without having to rewrite the code that reports on it.

Comment: can you show the actual definition / structure of the CriticalFailureCategory enum..?

Comment: can you show the actual definition / structure of the CriticalFailureCategory enum..? also your `Enum.GetName` is incorrect it should be something like this for example 
`var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(entry.Key)` or change the `foreach` to 
`foreach(var entry in Enum.GetValues(typeof(valueSource)))`

Comment: @MethodMan: Thanks. I didn't even reach the point where I could test that code since I couldn't call the function. I added the definition to the original post.

Comment: @MethodMan That's incorrect `typeof` requires a type name, not a instance of that type.

Comment: @juharr I use typeof to for example return the names of an enum with zero issues perhaps I am not giving a clear example..

Comment: @MethodMan The only use of `typeof` that I've seen work is the actual name of the type like `typeof(DateTime)`.  AFAIK it doesn't work with a variable.  You can use it on generic types though.

Comment: it works with an Enum I am looking at some existing code that I have just tested as well as what we use in our production currently if you are not familiar with other ways of doing it I would be happy to show you ...feel free to send me a private chat and I can show you exactly the how and why it works..

Comment: @MethodMan If you mean you have an `enum MyEnum...` and you use `typeof(MyEnum)` then sure, but `var someEnum = MyEnum.AEnum` with `typeof(someEnum)` doesn't even compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72603/discussion-between-methodman-and-juharr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `CountEnumOccurrence` generic for this to work.

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> CountEnumOccurrence<TEnum>(
    Dictionary<TEnum, List<string>> valueSource)
{
    var convertedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var entry in valueSource)
    {
        var name = Enum.GetName(entry.Key.GetType(), entry.Key);
        convertedDictionary.Add(name, entry.Value.Count);
    }

    return convertedDictionary;
}
```

If you want to constrain the `TEnum` type to only enums you can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum) to see how and why it has to be a partially run time check or you have to write MSIL.