# Compare two System.Enum of type T

Tags: c#, generics, enums, comparison

I just figured out that System.Enum is not easy to implement as a generic type. The compiler throws an error when **comparing two enums of type `T`**:

```
if(button.Identifier == Identifier) // (in AbstractInputDevice)
```

I believe I cannot compare these two Enums because **they are not actually known to be Enums**. And thus no comparison method is available. How do I compare them for equality?

Here are more details:

```
public class Button<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable {
   public TEnum Identifier {
        get;
        private set; //Set in the ctor
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class AbstractInputDevice<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable {

   private List<Button<TEnum>> _buttons = new List<Button<TEnum>>();

   public Button<TEnum> GetButton(TEnum Identifier){
        foreach(Button<TEnum> button in _buttons){
            if(button.Identifier == Identifier) //<- compiler throws
                return button;
        }
        Debug.Log("'" + GetType().Name + "' cannot return an <b>unregistered</b> '" + typeof(Button<TEnum>).Name + "' that listens to '" + typeof(TEnum).Name + "." + Identifier.ToString() + "'.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

An InputDevice might look like that:

```
public class Keyboard : AbstractInputDevice<KeyCode> {
    private void Useless(){
        Button<KeyCode> = GetButton(KeyCode.A);
    }
}
```

I used this resource:
[Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: What is the exact error the compiler is giving you?

Comment: You may want to try `button.Identifier.Equals(Identifier)`, and to make things more concise: `var button = _buttons.Where(b => b.Identifier.Equals(Identifier)).FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: @RonBeyer I use Unity3D and their compiler is sometimes a little confusing. Right now it says "unexpected symbol '=='" as if there would be a typo. But before some changes it said something different like "'==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TEnum and 'TEnum'"

Comment: I'd say you need to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alex Are you serius? No error anymore!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of the impossible

```
button.Identifier == Identifier
```

you should use

```
EqualityComparer<TEnum>.Default.Equals(button.Identifier, Identifier)
```

This avoids boxing the value into an `object` box (or `IComparable` box).

Comment: That would be a better compare, agreed

Comment: Alright, since Alex agreed to this solution (I already marked his as answer) I will mark this one instead.

Comment: @NoelWidmer You can still use Linq `_buttons.FirstOrDefault(b =>  EqualityComparer<TEnum>.Default.Equals(b.Identifier, Identifier))` much like Alex suggests, but it is more a matter of style and personal preference.

Comment: Interesting that `EqualityComparer(of enumType).Default` avoids boxing, given that enum types don't implement `IEquatable(themselves)`.  I wonder what `EqualityComparer(of T).Default` looks for besides `IEquatable`?

Comment: @supercat Maybe I was wrong, and maybe it ends up calling `Enum.Equals(object)`, with boxing, after all? Have you investigated it? Also, does `EqualityComparer(of Nullable(of SomeStruct)).Default.Equals` lead to boxing of the nullables?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It doesn't box, at least in my current .NET, which  makes me curious if there are other kinds of value types for which `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` includes optimization, and whether any such behaviors have changed since 2.0; it would certainly be possible to write a "make default equality comparer" method which would analyze the things being compared and generate code to do the appropriate comparisons, but I have no idea if .NET does so.

Comment: @supercat Simply looking at the run-time type of the `.Default` instance gives some clue. For an enum type `E` I get ``System.Collections.Generic.EnumEqualityComparer`1[E]``, so there exists special support for enums. Given that, surely they took care and avoided boxing. For a struct `G` which does implement ``IEquatable`1[G]``, I get ``System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[G]``. Finally, for a struct `N` with no generic equality support, I get ``System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[N]``. ***Addition:*** With .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: I wonder how hard it would have been to add a `ValueTypeBitwiseEqualityComparer` for structures that are bitwise-compared.  By my understanding, the default `ValueType.Equals` goes through the trouble of identifying whether a struct should be bitwise-compared and does a bitwise comparison if so, rather than calling `Equals` on all the members, but the benefit of doing that is somewhat muffled by the amount of work that gets repeated with every comparison.  I would think that for structs whose members are all bitwise-comparable performance could be...

Comment: ...improved significantly by such an optimization, though for best results it may be good to define an attribute for structs which implement `IEquatable<T>` but could be safely bitwise compared, so that when included in other structs the outer structs could also be bitwise compared.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a reference comparison on a value type (struct), use `Equals` for equality instead:

```
public Button<TEnum> GetButton(TEnum Identifier) {
    var button = _buttons
        .Where(b => EqualityComparer<TEnum>.Default.Equals(b.Identifier, Identifier))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (button == null)
        Debug.Log("'" + GetType().Name + "' cannot return an <b>unregistered</b> '" + typeof(Button<TEnum>).Name + "' that listens to '" + typeof(TEnum).Name + "." + Identifier.ToString() + "'.");
    return button;
}
```

The `button.Identifier == Identifier` statement cannot be performed, because the `==` operator does not exist for structs. On  a class it would have performed a reference comparison.

And as @JeppeStigNielsen noted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929791/2573395), to prevent a boxing equality comparison, it is better to use the `EqualityComparer<TEnum>.Default.Equals` method.

Comment: The .Equals() worked as said in the comments. But I do not understand how I should implement this new line you posted into my if statement...

Comment: @NoelWidmer added it in the context of your original `GetButton` method.

Comment: Is List<T>.Where an extension method? If so, do you know which namespace it is in? (It is not recognized as a member of _buttons)

Comment: @NoelWidmer Yes, you will need to add a `using System.Linq;` statement

Comment: Indeed - I do. Thank you very much!