# Generic enum constraint

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have inherited a web api that has lots of enums defined in code, I want to convert them to a view-model class called EnumView so they can be serialized as below...

> {Id: *value*, Name: *enumName*}

```
public class EnumView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Upon restricting the Generic class to the enum type, I get the warning

> Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Enum'

This is the generic converter that I was going to use...

```
public class EnumViewConverter<T> where T : Enum
{
    public static List<EnumView> ConvertToView()
    {
        List<EnumView> enumViews = new List<EnumView>();

        T[] enumValues = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

        foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        {
            var enumView = new EnumView
            {
                Id = (int)enumValue,
                Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), enumValue)
            };

            enumViews.Add(enumView);
        }
        return enumViews;
    }
}
```

Without T being constrained to an enum, the following conversion doesn't compile...

> Id = (int)enumValue,

Due to the issue around a lack of generic enum constraints, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Ok, you have a defined enum, but how are you going to use it? by answering this question, we find out the purpose of the conversion, then we can possibly come up with a solution

Comment: @leppie - I had read that question/answer before posting but don't feel it really answers my question.

Comment: @Hamed not sure quite what you're after - the EnumView is to be serialized in the API. The enum is used in serverside code...

Comment: actually `(int)enumValue` doesn't compile I guess.Because there's no guarantee that `enumValue` must be an `int`. BTW, `Enum`'s are serializable too.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yep, type T isn't guaranteed an enum if I use where T: struct for example. I want to create a list of all the values of the enum and return this in the API, not just serialize a single enum value.

Comment: @Will: As noted in the question, there is a way you can emulate this (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28527552/15541) If it is not a duplicate, explain why the solutions do not work for you.

Comment: @leppie so after testing enumView.Id = (int)EnumUtils.Parse<T>(enumView.Name); I still have the same issue...
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method 'EnumClassUtils<TClass>.Parse<TEnum>(string)'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.Enum'.

Comment: @Will: It seems your actual problem is casting to `int` from an unconstraint type. Would `Id = (int)(object)enumValue;` not be a solution for you?

Comment: @leppie unfortunately I don't think so - EnumUtils.Parse<T>(enumView.Name); even without the cast to int I get The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method 'EnumClassUtils<TClass>.Parse<TEnum>(string)'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.Enum'.

Comment: @leppie thanks for your suggestions so far - the answer suggested as a duplicate allows converting a string back to a well know concrete type of enum but not using a generic in it's place i.e. the calling EnumUtils.Parse<T>("enumValue")

Comment: You will have to duplicate the nested class pattern found in that answer instead of trying to call `EnumUtils.Parse` directly i.e. define a `ViewConverter<TClass>` and then define `EnumViewConverter : ViewConverter<Enum>`. The class nesting is used to emulate the constraint on `T` so you can't call it from other generic code.

Comment: @Lee sorry not quite keeping up with you...please can you post a bit more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use : Id = Convert.ToInt32(enumValue) instead of the casting (int)

And if you want to add some 'constraint' to check the type at the compilation you could set  'where T : struct' it will at least prevent to set class type.

Comment: thanks, I thought I had tested this already and it hadn't worked; anyhow, tried again and you're spot on.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used...

```
public static class EnumViewConverter<T> where T : struct
{
    public static List<EnumView> ConvertToView()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");

        List<EnumView> enumViews = new List<EnumView>();

        T[] enumValues = (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

        foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        {
            var enumView = new EnumView
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(enumValue),
                Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(T), enumValue)
            };

            enumViews.Add(enumView);
        }
        return enumViews;
    }
}
```

Called by...

```
var views = EnumViewConverter<FooBarEnum>.ConvertToView();
```

Thanks for all the help, could have sworn I tried this earlier:(

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my earlier comment, the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum/28527552#28527552) uses a nested class with a generic parameter dependent on its parent class to emulate generic `Enum` constraints. You could use this approach here:

```
public abstract class ConverterClassUtils<TClass> 
    where TClass : class
{
    public class ViewConverter<TInner> where TInner : struct, TClass
    {
        public static List<EnumView> ConvertToView()
        {
            List<EnumView> enumViews = new List<EnumView>();

            TInner[] enumValues = (TInner[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TInner));

            foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
            {
                var enumView = new EnumView
                {
                    Id = (int)(object)enumValue,
                    Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(TInner), enumValue)
                };

                enumViews.Add(enumView);
            }
            return enumViews;
        }
    }
}

public class EnumConverter : ConverterClassUtils<Enum> { }
```

then the following compiles:

```
var view = EnumConverter.ViewConverter<SomeEnum>.ConvertToView();
```

while this does not:

```
var view = EnumConverter.ViewConverter<int>.ConvertToView();
```

Comment: thanks for expanding on your suggestion, in the end I went with the code below as it was simpler. Thanks for your help.