# override an enum with a custom enum in the inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

I have a class:

```
public abstract class Criteria
{
    public virtual Enum Field
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string FieldData;
}
```

I have an enum:

```
public enum MyFieldsEnum
{
    Name=1,
    Age=2,
    Gender=3,
}
```

I have an inherited class:

```
public class MyCriteria : Criteria
{
    MyFieldsEnum myfields;
    public override MyFieldsEnum Field
    {
        get
        {
            return myfields;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to return the MyFieldsEnum rather than the blank Enum
Field. But the above code does not work and does not accept
MyFieldsEnum for Field. **It gives the error: "Type must be enum to match overridden member Criteria.Field"**

Is it possible in some way or the other?

Comment: can you use generics?

Comment: "does not work" is *never* enough information. What happens vs what you want to happen? (But no, you can't override a property of one type with a property of a different type.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. What I am trying to achieve is: I want to have a base class but the inherited class will implement their own version of Enum. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks a lot. Trying it now.

Comment: You still haven't clarified the question. What error do you receive? Yes, I could guess - but I shouldn't have to. The detail should be in the question - including the motivation.

Comment: @JonSkeet It gives the error: "Type must be enum to match overridden member Criteria.Field".

Comment: Right. So please edit that into the question. As I said initially, a question should never contain "the above code does not work" without explaining in what *way* it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My vote would be to change it to use generics.

```
public abstract class Criteria<TEnum>
   where TEnum : struct, IConvertable  // Edit: C# 7.2 TEnum:System.Enum works.
{
     public T Field { get; set; }
}

public class MyCriteria : Criteria<MyFieldsEnum>
{
   // No need to override Field
}
```

Be warned that C#/CLR does not at present support enum as a type constraint period to C# 7.2. You can do `TEnum: System.Enum` in C#7.2 , but here is more information: [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: Thanks. How can I read the Field value as an enum in the implemented code?

Comment: @Satyajit that sounds like a separate question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot override `Enum` from the base class you can use `generics` instead, with generic constrains since `Enum` is a `struct` and an `IConvertible` (*Also, please read the note in the end*):

```
public abstract class Criteria<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public virtual T Field
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string FieldData;
}

public class MyCriteria : Criteria<MyFieldsEnum>
{
    MyFieldsEnum myfields;
    public override MyFieldsEnum Field
    {
        get
        {
            return myfields;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Other way is to check this at runtime but this is more risky and will require the developer using this class to know that the returned `Enum` from the `get` method is `MyFieldsEnum`:

```
public class MyCriteria : Criteria
{
    MyFieldsEnum myfields;
    public override Enum Field
    {
        get
        {
            return myfields;
        }

        set
        {
            if (!(value is MyFieldsEnum))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set enums other than MyFieldsEnum");
            }
            base.Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

***Note: Anyway before you do that, you should reconsider `Enum` as your abstract type since if you think about it, any code that will refer `Criteria` as an `abstract class` will have to know that actual `Enum` you are using in order to do something will it, so you better be type safe and reconsider if this abstraction really gives you any benefit***.